# Module Wide Factory Object

Tags: magento2, factory

In Magento 2, would it be wrong to create a Factory model that allows me to get a factory for any of the models in my module? The reason I ask is that injecting model factories into my blocks/controllers where I need them and it is becoming quite difficult to manage. The proposed Factory of factories model I propose would still use DI to inject the factory classes so nothing would be hardcoded.

Here's some example code:

```
namespace Vendor/Module/Model;

class Factory
{
    protected $_factories = null;

    public function __construct(
        FirstModelFactory $firstModelFactory,
        SecondModelFactory $secondModelFactory
    ) {
        $this->_factories = array(
            'FirstModelFactory' => $firstModelFactory,
            'SecondModelFactory' => $secondModelFactory
        );
    }

    public function getFactory($class)
    {
        return isset($this->_factories[$class])
            ? $this->_factories[$class]
            : false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not wrong, but **a)** you're duplicating the responsibility of the Obj Manager and **b)** thus means you're actually injecting a quasi-Obj Manager, which is in itself not recommended, for various reasons (discussed [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly)).

So, to be frank, I don't see the point in doing that.

Comment: It's not duplicating the object manager though because my Factory class includes all of the factories via the constructor, meaning it still uses the DI system (where as the Object Manager does not). By using this method I can include 1 object into specific files (abstract block, model and controller) and have access to the models where ever I need them while still using DI and allowing the factories to be switched out for unit testing.

Comment: It's duplicating in the sense that your Factory is not only creating objects, it _stores_ them, too (for caching, sure). In this sense, it's an _object pool_. Just like the Object Manager. I didn't say they're _identical_, just similar enough to make your Factory class have the same disadvantages when used directly. I understand why you'd want _one_ object instead of injecting 1000. But I still wouldn't use such a factory. I'd try refactor my existing class design, instead.