# Magento 2: How to redirect customer to login page

Tags: magento2, login, redirect

How can I check customer is logged in or not? If *customer is not logged in then how to redirect him to the login page*?

I want to do this from `.phtml` file. So please help me as per that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to do it directly from `.phtml` file use following code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$customerSession = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$urlInterface = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');

if(!$customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    $customerSession->setAfterAuthUrl($urlInterface->getCurrentUrl());
    $customerSession->authenticate();
}
```

Then after login you will be automatically redirected to current view.

But using Object Manager isn't good practice. You should use dependency injection whenever possible.

Comment: Direct instances of Object Manager are not best practice: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/117101/1956

Comment: Still, Magento core team uses it in few models. The question was how to do it directly from .phtml file, and this is the answer :)

Comment: Szubert ... fair enough...just good to note, I suppose.

Comment: Why it is going to infinite redirect loop

Answer (score 11):

@Krupali, if you're adamant about your code being implemented in a template, then @Bartlomiej Szubert's example is the better choice. Generally, it's best practice to hide away those implementation details from your template and abstract the logic away to something else (block or helper).

Here's an example of a helper implementation:

```
<?php

namespace Ryan\CustomerRedirect\Helper;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class Customer extends AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    private $customerSession;
    /**
     * @var UrlInterface
     */
    private $urlInterface;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $customerSession,
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->urlInterface = $context->getUrlBuilder();
    }

    public function redirectIfNotLoggedIn()
    {
        if (!$this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->customerSession->setAfterAuthUrl($this->urlInterface->getCurrentUrl());
            $this->customerSession->authenticate();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your template you can use something like this:

```
$this->helper('Ryan\CustomerRedirect\Helper\Customer')->redirectIfNotLoggedIn()
```

*namespace shown is an example

This way your code can be reused elsewhere...and if you decide to change the implementation logic of how you're checking if someone is logged in, you don't have to change your template(s).

Comment: Oh yes. This is very useful to me.

Comment: @Krupali, I'm glad that this is helpful. You know, you can show that something is helpful by upvoting it :D

Comment: helper in  template actually is also using OM, but just nicely hidden :)

Comment: Worked for me with all caches enabled. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple `di.xml` pref for this:

```
    <type name="Vendor\Module\Your\Controller">
        <plugin name="auth-redirect-plugin" type="Magento\Customer\Controller\Plugin\Account"/>
    </type>
```

Don't need to write code when Magento already wrote it