# How to add order price total next to cart icon in header?

Tags: magento2

I need to add the totals next to the cart icon, atm the last developers made a JS script in the header that loaded the total to there, it worked poorly but now we updated to 2.3 and works even more poorly the total is most of the time at 0.00. So I want to delete this thing they made and do a proper one, the problem is, what's the best way to accomplish that?

I want something like this[image]

But with the right value, that is the broken one but gives an idea.

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

display cart items sub-total

Add code to **minicart.phtml** to display cart items total

```
<span data-bind="html: getCartParam('subtotal')"></span>
```

after run command

> php bin/magento cache:clean

More Ref...[Click](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148983/magento-2-show-cart-items-total-to-header-cart-link)