# Get Customer custom data in product page in Magento2

Tags: magento2, product

I have added a custom link in My Account page, In that link I have added custom collection.
I Would like to get that custom Collection of specified customer in Product view page.

Help me great.

Thanks

Comment: Please describe more. Custom data or customer data ??

Comment: Please find the updated question.

Comment: it is custom data of customer.

Comment: Your custom data store in customer table or your custom table ??

Comment: have you store customer ID in your custom table ?

Comment: yes, I am saving the customer id in custom table.

Answer (score 3):

create your custom table Model files for get your custom collection.

**VendoreName\ModuleName\Model**

**CustomData.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
use VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\CustomData as CustomDataResourceModel;

class CustomData extends AbstractModel
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(CustomDataResourceModel::class);
    }
}
```

**VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel**

**CustomData.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class CustomData extends AbstractDb
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('your_table_name', 'your_primary_key_column_name');
    }
}
```

**VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\CustomData**

**Collection.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\CustomData;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\CustomData as CustomDataModel;
use VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\CustomData as CustomDataResourceModel;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            CustomDataModel::class,
            CustomDataResourceModel::class
        );
    }
}
```

Now ready to get custom collection

Add to your block file

```
protected $customCollection;

public function __construct(
    ..............................................
    ..............................................
    \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession,
    \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\CustomData\CollectionFactory $customCollection,
    ..............................................
    ..............................................
) {
   ..............................................
   .............................................. 
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession->create();
    $this->customCollection = $customCollection;
    ..............................................
    ..............................................
}

public function getCustomDataCollection()
{
    //get current customer id
    $cust_id = $this->getCustomerId();

    // filter custom data with customer id
    $Mycollection = $this->customCollection ->create();
    $Mycollection ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $cust_id);
    return $Mycollection ;
}
public function getCustomerId()
{
    return $this->_customerSession->getId();
}
```

> Note:- Here replace **customer_id** with your store column name which store customer id.

you can call this in your phtml file

```
$block->getCustomDataCollection();
```

Run Magento command

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:f
php bin/magento c:c
```

If your block not get customer ID add **cacheable='false'**. In your layout file.

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: @shivashankarm try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121271/magento-2-get-cart-quote-total-in-minicart-phtml

Comment: @shivashankarm I will never do it but I try this and I form you when done.

Comment: Hi @Shivashankarm above solution is works for you ?