# Get the Email response after send an email using php

Tags: php

Can anyone help me how to get the sent email response of shared content.

```
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 
$from = 'From: yoursite.com'; 
$to = 'contact@yoursite.com'; 

$subject = 'Customer Inquiry'; 

$body = "From:" .$name."\r\n E-Mail:" .$email."\r\n Message:\r\n" .$message; 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) 
    { 
        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>'; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
    } 
}
```

i will add email share button on product page, if that product is shared via email, i will give reward points to customer.

Help me great.

Thanks

Comment: Please explain bit more.

Comment: I would like to add some functionality to based upon mail sent response, Is there any posibility to do like that

Comment: Sent response ?? What you want after sent email ?

Comment: i will add email share button on product page, if that product is shared via email, i will give reward points to customer.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: iam trying above code,  iam getting success message after share, but at the same time i want response also

Comment: check and update me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i would like to give points only once per product, Don't give points for same product.

Comment: you need to check email is sent or not so how you check this ?

Comment: you need to check via custom table in which reward point history will store.

Comment: if i get the product link after shared based on that i will add, can we get that product link, after successfully shared.

Comment: if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) 
    { 
        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>'; 

        $responce = 1; // for method-2 check email send

        /* Method-1  you can add your  reward points to customer code here also */ 
    }

Comment: i would like to get that link in this condition, after response

Comment: yes we can get link in if condition. but here point is per customer or some condition vise ?

Comment: have you not give any respone to this answer please be do first https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/306628/get-customer-custom-data-in-product-page-in-magento2

Comment: for one customer only one product share

Comment: yes here you need to create one table which store this data.

Comment: please be give responce to answer

Comment: okay How to get that link after sharing only.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107131/discussion-on-question-by-shivashankar-m-get-the-email-response-after-send-an-em).

Comment: please update me

Answer (score 1):

> **Try this way**

```
/* Method -2 we check email is sent or not */

$responce = 0; // for methos-2 email not send

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 
$from = 'From: yoursite.com'; 
$to = 'contact@yoursite.com'; 

$subject = 'Customer Inquiry'; 

$body = "From:" .$name."\r\n E-Mail:" .$email."\r\n Message:\r\n" .$message; 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) 
    { 
        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>'; 

        $responce = 1; // for method-2 check email send

        /* Method-1  you can add your  reward points to customer code here also */ 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
    } 
}


if ($responce == 1) 
{
    /* Method-2  you can add your  reward points to customer code here also */
}
```

Comment: okay, i will try with this and let you know

Comment: please update me .