# How to display cart item count in custom header using JavaScript?

Tags: magento2, javascript, cart, addtocart, knockoutjs

I've created a custom header that works fine. I replaced Magento's cart, and instead added a shopping basket icon in the header. Like so:

[image]

When pressed it redirects to the cart.

What I want to do is add the number if items in the users cart using JavaScript so that when a user pressed "add to cart" it also updates the number next to the bag showing how many items are in the basket.

I followed the suggestion here: [Magento 2 Get Cart Quote Total in minicart.phtml](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121271/magento-2-get-cart-quote-total-in-minicart-phtml)

I placed `<span data-bind="html: getCartParam('subtotal')"></span>` in the HTML but got an error `getCartParam is undefined`

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What version of Magento are you on?

Comment: Magento shows that by default with shoppingcart icon. Isn't it?

Comment: Magento 2.4. And I'm using a custom header without the use of Magento's cart implementation.

Comment: That is a function of the elements js file being called by knockout. Looks like the function isn't available to knockout. Check your headers supporting js files.

Comment: Thanks Mark. You could be right because I replaced the header the cart js is not being included. I shall check this.