# Magento 2: Get all category products by category name

Tags: magento2, php, custom-block

anyone knows how to load from my custom block.php all the products of a specific category,

I would like to get them by the name of the category and not by the id.

I tried to change the standard code used by magento `\Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList`

here is the code:

```
public function createCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->setVisibility($this->catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

    $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->setPageSize($this->getPageSize())
        ->setCurPage($this->getRequest()->getParam(self::PAGE_VAR_NAME, 1));

    $conditions = $this->getConditions();
    $conditions->collectValidatedAttributes($collection);
    $this->sqlBuilder->attachConditionToCollection($collection, $conditions);

    return $collection;
}
```

but this code get all categories products.

Comment: welcome ,MSe, You  have you tried anyting?

Comment: @AmitBera  I edit my question with my test

Comment: what you mean by `I would like to get them by the name of the category and not by the id`. Are  you get category by category name?

Comment: Yes I want to load the category not by id, but by the name.

Answer (score 1):

You need **inject  factory class**  `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory`  to  `__construct()` function in order get category by name

```
  <?php
     namespace [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Block;
         /**
          * @var Category
          */
     class Categories extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template     
         protected $_categoryCollectionFactory;

        public function __construct(
             \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
             \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory
 $categoryCollectionFactory,
             array $data = []
         ) {
            $this->categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
             parent::__construct($context, $data);
         }

         public function getCategoriesbyName($name)
         {
            $categoryCollection = $this->categoryCollectionFactory->create();
             $categories = $categoryCollection->addAttributeToFilter('name', $name);
             return $categories;
         }
      }
```

Comment: It works to get category, now I could get the products of the selected category?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Block;

class [ClassName] extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template{


    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory
     */
    protected $categoryFactory;



    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
    array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    }


    public function getCategoryName()
    {
        $categoryName =  "mobiles";
        $category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->addAttributeToFilter('name', $categoryName);
        return $category;
    }


    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->getCategoryName()->getProductCollection();
        return $collection;
    }

}
```

feel free to ask if any queries.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to get all category products by category name.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$name = 'Gear'; //category name
$categoryobj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
$categoryproductcollection = $categoryobj->create()->load($name, 'name')->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Comment: This will technically work, though it is considered suboptimal to use the ObjectManager directly: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly