# Magento2: How to create password protected cms page?

Tags: cms, magento2.2.3, password

I want to create password protected page.
Where users once click on password protected page then they redirect to the password page. And then after filling password, they redirect on actual page content. manage session and all.

Comment: Please specify Magento version in your question.

Comment: Version: Magento 2.2.3

Answer (score 0):

To make the **cms pages**, you  have to  use `event/observer`

> controller_action_predispatch_cms_page_view

ON this event,fire an observer which will check current user is **loggedin or not**.
If user is not  loggedin this redirect to  login page.

**events.xml** define at `app/code/{vendorname}/{ModuleName}/etc/frontend/` at code  is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_cms_page_view">
        <observer name="add_login_checker" 
        instance="{VendorName}\{Modulename}\Observer\RestrictCmsPage" />
    </event>       
</config>
```

**Observer file `RestrictCmsPage.php` located at `app/code/{vendorname}/{ModuleName}/Observer/`  Observer code like**

```
<?php
namespace {VendorName}\{Modulename}\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;

class RestrictCmsPage implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag
     */
    protected $_actionFlag;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */

    public function __construct(
        CustomerSession $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect
        )
    {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_actionFlag = $actionFlag;
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
    }
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        if (!$this->customerSession->authenticate()) {

            $this->_actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
            if (!$this->customerSession->getBeforeUrl()) {
                $this->customerSession->setBeforeUrl($this->redirect->getRefererUrl());
            }
        }
        return  $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do so. I would recommend not to override the controller action. I would rather prefer to use either Magento 2 plugin feature or use events and observers method.

If you want to use Events and Observers, then you can observe the event:\

**`controller_action_predispatch_cms_page_view`**'

or

**`controller_action_predispatch`** (If you want to cover more actions rather than only cms pages)

and then write your conditional redirection to the login page.

You can take help from this [tutorial post](https://inchoo.net/magento/restrict-website-access-require-log/).

Answer (score 0):

There are **two** way.

**First**

> Make CMS pages available only to logged in customers

[Reference 1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122204/magento-2-restrict-access-to-cms-page)

[Reference 2](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-make-cms-pages-available-only-to.html)

```
You can use this code in any phtml file to redirect to login page:

 <?php 
        $obm = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $redirect = $obm->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http');
        $context = $obm->get('Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context');
        $cmsPage = $obm->get('\Magento\Cms\Model\Page');

        $pageIdentifier = $cmsPage->getIdentifier(); // CMS Page Identifier

        $isLoggedIn = $context->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);

        if($pageIdentifier == 'cms-page-identifier' && !$isLoggedIn)
        {
           $redirect->setRedirect('customer/account/login/');
        }
 ?>
```

**Second**

> I am not 100% convinced its secure but seems to block the CMS page
>   unless you have entered the right password.  Add this to the top of
>   your CMS page content:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var password = 'password'
    var retVal = prompt("Enter your password : ", "your password here");
    if(retVal !== password)
    {
        location.assign('#');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If the page has information that must be kept secure DO NOT UNDER ANY CIRCUMSTANCES USE THE JS EXAMPLE. If you do it is trivial to bypass as you are *literally* transmitting the password to all users of your website.