# Magento 2: how to get Model in Block

Tags: magento2, blocks, model

I want to use an instance of a Model into a Block.

in Magento 1 they uses:

```
$exple = Mage::getModel('exple/standard');
```

How can I do this with Magento 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use below code to call the model from anywhere

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$model = $objectManager->create('\Namespace\Modulename\Model\Modelname');
```

Comment: Using the object manager directly is not recommended. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly

Answer (score 11):

Override constructor in your block class and add your class factory as dependency.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Vendor\Exple\Model\StandardFactory $modelFactory,
    array $data = []
) {
      $this->modelFactory = $modelFactory;
      parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

function someMetod() {
    $model =  $this->modelFactory->create();
}
```

Comment: If I need to use my class factory in many methods of my block, have I to call _create()_ factory method in everywhere? Or should I call I only one time? And in this case, where?

Comment: How to use it for eav/entity_attribute ?

Answer (score 8):

You can instantiate your model by using `constructor`. You can call it by **ObjectManager directly** but passing by constructor is the best approach.

**Example by using constructor**

```
protected $customer;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
 * @param \Demo\HelloWorld\Model\Customer $customer
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Demo\HelloWorld\Model\Customer $customer
) {
    $this->customer = $customer;

    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

`$this->customer` is your model instances.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is it a correct way (best practice) in Magento 2 or it should be better to use class factory as dependency as suggested by @KAndy?

Answer (score 0):

Get the instance of a factory for your model using dependency injection.
You don't need to define the factory explicitly, because factories are an automatically generated class type. When you reference a factory in a class constructor, Magento’s object manager generates the factory class if it does not exist. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/code-generation.html

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Helloworld\News\Model\NewsFactory $newsFactory,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->newsFactory = $newsFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
```

Calling the create() method on a factory gives you an instance of its specific class.

```
$model = $this->newsFactory->create();
```