# How to get store phone number in magento 2

Tags: magento2, template, configuration

I want to display phone number saved in magento admin in frontend in magento 2.

Like in magento 1.9 its like

`$storePhone = Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/phone');`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll have to use the `Magento/Store/Model/Information` class and call the `getStoreInformationObject()` method for that.

### Recommended way

You'll have to inject this class in your custom block to be able to use that in your template though.

```
protected $_storeInfo;

public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Store\Model\Information $storeInfo,
    ....
) {
    ...
    $this->_storeInfo = $storeInfo;
    ....
}
```

Then create a custom method to retrieve the phone number:

```
public function getPhoneNumber()
{
    return $this->_storeInfo->getStoreInformationObject(Store $store)->getPhone();
}
```

Thus in your template you can call:

```
$block->getPhoneNumber();
```

### Unrecommended way

You should never use the object manager directly (see why here: [To use or not to use the ObjectManager directly?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly))

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeInformation = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Store\Model\Information');
$storeInfo = $storeInformation->getStoreInformationObject($store);
```

Then you can get the phone by calling:

```
$phone = $storeInfo->getPhone();
```

Comment: how to implement it using object manager in phtml

Comment: @parasarora1303 see my edit but you should never use the object manager directly

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism : I'm getting an error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function dispatch() on null in vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php on line 644 --After clearing cache and all....

Comment: You need to pass the store as an argument of the function getStoreInformationObject

Comment: This answer still is not right. $store is not defined.

Comment: @Cypher909 to get $store, checking here Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface::getStore()

Answer (score 11):

you need to inject the an instance of `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface` in your block.

```
protected $scopeConfig;
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    ....
) {
    ...
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    ....
}
```

Then create the method `getStorePhone()`

```
public function getStorePhone()
{
    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
        'general/store_information/phone',
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    );
}
```

and call in your template `echo $block->getStorePhone()`

Answer (score 8):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$storeInformation = $objectManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\Information');

$store = $objectManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\Store');

$storeInfo = $storeInformation->getStoreInformationObject($store);

$phone = $storeInfo->getPhone();
```

Answer (score 1):

Above methods was not working for so I've tried in following way and it's working for me...

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class Contact extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_storeInfo;
    protected $_storeManagerInterface;


    public function __construct( 
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\Information $storeInfo,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManagerInterface,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data); 
        $this->_storeInfo = $storeInfo;
        $this->_storeManagerInterface = $storeManagerInterface;
    }
    public function getPhoneNumber()
    {
        return $this->_storeInfo->getStoreInformationObject($this->_storeManagerInterface->getStore(null))->getPhone();
    }
}
```

and in template file I've called

```
echo $block->getPhoneNumber();
```

Answer (score 1):

The above code is not working for me . I have tried the following code that works.

```
class Sociallinks extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
   protected $socialLinksHelper;
   protected $objMgr;
   protected $storeInfo;
   protected $scopeConfig;


   public function __construct(
      \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
      \Addpeople\Websettings\Helper\Data $myModuleHelper,
      array $data = []
    ) {

    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->_socialLinksHelper = $myModuleHelper;
    $this->_objMgr =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $storeInformation = $this->_objMgr->create('Magento\Store\Model\Information');
    $store = $this->_objMgr->create('Magento\Store\Model\Store');
    $this->_storeInfo = $storeInformation->getStoreInformationObject($store);

}

public function getPhoneNumber()
{

    return $this->_storeInfo->getPhone();

}
}
```

Template file

`<?php echo $block->getPhoneNumber();?>`

Answer (score 0):

We can also use :

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
$storePhone = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('general/store_information/phone');
```