# Magento 2 : Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function dispatch() | Store Information

Tags: magento2, blocks, email, address, magento-2.1.2

I'm trying to get store information which are set in backend like email,contact,address etc...(I've taken reference from here : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/125359/39607 )

To do so I've created a module

Following is my block file...

```
Contact.php

<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class Contact extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_storeInfo;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\Information $storeInfo
    )
    {        
        $this->_storeInfo = $storeInfo;
    }
    public function getPhoneNumber()
    {
        return $this->_storeInfo->getInformationObject()->getPhone();
    }

}
```

And in my phtml I'm calling like this :

```
<?php
    echo "Phone: ".$block->getPhoneNumber();
?>
```

But it's not working and showing me an error :

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
>   dispatch() on null in
>   vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php on line 644 (
>   ! ) Error: Call to a member function dispatch() on null in
>   vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php on line 644

What can be the issue here??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I've done in following way...But I don't it's proper way to do so or not...

```
    namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class Contact extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_storeInfo;
    protected $_storeManagerInterface;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Store\Model\Information $storeInfo,
    array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_storeInfo = $storeInfo;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    public function getPhoneNumber()
    {
        return $this->_storeInfo->getStoreInformationObject($this->_storeManager->getStore())->getPhone();
}
```

and in template file I've called

```
echo $block->getPhoneNumber();
```

**UPDATE:**

We don't need to use `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface` as it's already in parent class. We can directly use it vai `$this->_storeManager`

Comment: @Raphael at Digital Pianism : Is it proper way?? In getStoreInformationObject method it require store object that's why I had to use $_storeManagerInterface...

Comment: Yes that looks good. Not sure if you need to pass `null` to the `getStore` method though

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism : Yes, You are right as always, No need to pass null :) Thanks

Answer (score 6):

It's because your constructor does not match the parent block constructor. (the `...` in my answer you linked are important).

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Store\Model\Information $storeInfo,
    array $data = []
)
{        
    $this->_storeInfo = $storeInfo;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
```

Comment: But after doing so I'm getting following error now

( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Store\Model\Information::getInformationObject() in \www\m2\app\code\Package\Module\Block\Contact.php on line 26

Comment: @KaushalSuthar there was a mistake in my original post you linked. It must be `getStoreInformationObject` instead of `getInformationObject`

Comment: Now I'm getting error like this : 
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Store\Model\Information::getStoreInformationObject() must be an instance of Magento\Store\Model\Store, none given, called in m2\app\code\Package\Module\Block\Contact.php on line 26 and defined in m2\vendor\magento\module-store\Model\Information.php on line 79 :(

Comment: @KaushalSuthar I get that error as well. I suppose that the context needs to be in its own class.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,  
                \Magento\Store\Model\Information $storeInfo,  
                \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager ,
                array $data = [] ) { 
             $this->_storeInfo = $storeInfo;
             $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
             parent::__construct($context, $data); 
    }
```

Make sure you are working in developer mode and clear your generation folder by

```
rm -rf var/generation/*
```

did you tried like this?

```
   public function getPhoneNumber()
    {
        return $this->_storeInfo->getStoreInformationObject($this->_storeManager->getStore())->getPhone();
    }
```

Comment: Error : Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Store\Model\Information::getStoreInformationObject() must be an instance of Magento\Store\Model\Store, none given, called in m2\app\code\Package\Module\Block\Contact.php on line 26 and defined in m2\vendor\magento\module-store\Model\Information.php on line 79

Comment: update your code and clear the generation folder

Comment: yes I did, But still

Comment: try my updated code

Comment: I've already posted answer by myself, thanks anyway

Comment: Very helpful ! rm -rf var/generation/* was just enough for me