# Magento 2 - Get hours of operation

Tags: magento2, store-view

I am trying to get the hours of operation (preferably using the object manager), but I cannot find a way to do this...

Comment: give more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will help you:

[How to get store phone number in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125354/how-to-get-store-phone-number-in-magento-2)

Just take the hours, not the phone.

Comment: I found my answer in that question! :)

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code in the block.

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class Footerlink extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
protected $flHelper;
protected $_urlInterface;
protected $scopeConfig;


public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface,
    ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Addpeople\Websettings\Helper\Footerlink $myModuleHelper,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->_flHelper = $myModuleHelper;
    $this->_urlInterface = $urlInterface;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;

}
public function getOpeningHours()
{

    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('general/store_information/hours',ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

}
}
```