# Show telephone number on customer dashboard

Tags: magento2, overrides

How do i display the telephonenumber on customer dashboard?

I have extended the original class to add some functions, but I can't find the right way to show customer number. I read that telephonenumber that is related to the address.

This is my class:

```
<?php
namespace Portail\Customer\Block;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;

class Info extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info
{

    public function testTxt(){
        return 'bonjour';
    }

    public function getTelephoneCustomer(){

        $customerData = $this->getCustomer();
        $telephone = $customerData->getDefaultShippingAddress()->getTelephone();

        return $telephone;

    }

}
```

When I tried to reload my page, the loading is just stop, there no error.

Comment: Look at this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125354/how-to-get-store-phone-number-in-magento-2
The dashboard is created using multiple .phtml files and included by .xml. The dashboard is customer_account_index.xml (if I recall correctly). Try to combine this, maybe by altering the template `Magento_Customer::account/dashboard/info.phtml`

Comment: I've seen this topic, but it's to get the store phone number right ? I want to have the customer number

Answer (score 1):

If you have created your **custom** `customer attribute` manually, you can simply use this in the phtml:

```
$objm = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objm->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) 
{
    echo $customerSession->getCustomer()->getCustomAttribute(); //custom_attribute
}
```

Comment: It's not with a custom attribute, I want to use the native function of magento 2 (through address)

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in your info block

[image]

Answer (score 0):

***You can try below code to display TelePhone***

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomerAddress');
echo $customerSession->getDefaultBillingAddress()->getTelephone();
```

***Try To avoid Object-manager approach.***