# Class Mage not found in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, fatal-error

I'm new to Magento 2.

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage' not found in \vendor\magento\module-theme\view\base\templates\root.phtml on line 23

Can anybody tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Please add more details, you should add more code lines.

Comment: plz show your root.phtml file tomore debug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Mage`  is deprecated in Magento2.

**Magento2, not using factory Patten types like**  **Mage::getModel ,Mage::getsingleton()**   etc

It now uses the class **nameSpace** concept

To learn more about how to use ObjectManager in Magento 2, checkout these links:

- [alan storm blog](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_instance_objects)
- [Magento 2: to use or not to use the ObjectManager directly?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the theme you installed is not compatible with Magento 2.
Aparently it has a `Mage::...()` call in one of the files.

Answer (score -1):

in magento 2 call the model any where

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$model = $objectManager->create('\Namespace\Modulename\Model\Modulename');
```

Comment: Don't use the ObjectManager directly https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/117103/5972