# Magento 2: Prevent customer account auto registration

Tags: magento2, customer-account, register

Anyone know the best method to prevent automatic customer account registration? there is a captcha method any other?

Comment: what u mean by `automatic customer account registration`?

Comment: I mean bots registering, by filling forms fields....

Comment: why you did not use capctha

Comment: M2 default captcha not working in my system(not showing captcha) not sure why :( I enabled forom M2 backend cleared caches,

Answer (score 0):

With Magento2 first thing is form Key and second thing is captcha this two combination should result in spamming controls.

Also apply some IP rules at robot level to blocks known IP range from countries that do most of the spamming.

Comment: Sorry can you describe more about "form Key" I am using default M2 registration form is anything I should do with or..

Comment: And you know how I can determine customer registered country and IP etc...

Comment: Magento default uses formkey.Go through this link :http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131189/magento-2-what-is-the-use-of-formkey

Comment: https://github.com/Vinai/customer-registration-ip for customer IP collection.

Comment: https://www.fmeextensions.com/geo-ip-ultimate-lock-magento-2.html  or you can use this module.