# invalid form key. please refresh the page. magento 2

Tags: magento2

Getting the error...

> invalid form key. please refresh the page

when creating a new user. Even after following these steps.

I set in file **`php.ini`** variable **`max_input_vars`** increase it to 10000 through.
Than cleared `var/cache`.

Still the customer is not able to create a new account or post the form. 
Does anyone know how to solve it ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: check you console and let me know the error no for certain request

Comment: The console is clear. but the page after submission displays error and the page keeps reloading.

Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page. 
Also this is when create account.

Comment: frontend or backend?

Comment: https://ibb.co/HFhVvhs

front-end

Comment: Can you reset the URL to magento store root Ex: <host>/Magento/customer/account/create/ and try. Some time the key may be expired if you try refresh the same URL it will throw this exception.

Comment: i got same issue while using Chrome But Works Fine in FIreFox

Comment: Ok, what about this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/293597/82680 ?

Comment: @BalaVaradarajan I am running the magento on my localhost.

Comment: @WaqarAli yes this is working on firefox exactly correct.