# Contact form as API endpoint?

Tags: email, contact-us

I am building a contact form which calls a post controller and emails some of the posted values to a specified recipient.

My question Is How can I'secure' this form other than CAPTCHA? I looked at the Magento Contact form and that doesn't seem to have any mechanisms to stop someone simply calling the POST method and spamming the site.

Obviously I am checking/sanitizing inputs, but it seems like I should be at least incorporating a nonce or some kind of barrier.

Is there a 'best practice' in Magento?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Magento uses form_key to preventing against **Cross Site Request Forgery**. So you should use that first before the CAPTCHA option.

Reference post: [Magento 2 - What is the use of formkey](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131189/magento-2-what-is-the-use-of-formkey)