# Magento2: Load Model Data By Another Field

Tags: magento2, module, collection, data, object-manager

I have below table named "messages".

```
id | posts_id  | message_description | created_at
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      1           test1             2016-09-06 10:00:00
2      1           test2             2016-09-06 11:00:00
3      2           test1             2016-09-06 10:00:00
4      2           test2             2016-09-06 11:00:00
```

**app\code\Custom\Module\Block\Edit.php**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$messages = $objectManager->create('Custom\Module\Model\Messages')->loadByPostsId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
return $messages;
```

I would like to retrieve messages by posts_id. How can i get that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to **use collections** for that:

```
$messages = $objectManager->create('Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Messages\Collection')->addFieldToFilter('posts_id', $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
```

This is **assuming you have created a collection resource model for your `Messages` entity.**

NB: please [try to avoid using the Object Manager directly](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly)

Instead you can **inject the collection class in your constructor**:

```
protected $_messagesCollection;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Messages\Collection $messagesCollection,
    ...)
{
    ...
    $this->_messagesCollection = $messagesCollection;
}
```

And then you can use your variable directly in your code:

```
$messages = $this->_messagesCollection->addFieldToFilter('posts_id', $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
```

Answer (score 14):

**You don't need to use collection for that.**

Just call the `load` function, with a second parameter, the field.

Inject the factory in the construct where you need to retrieve your model

```
protected $messagesFactory;

public function __construct(\Custom\Module\Model\MessagesFactory $messagesFactory){
    $this->_messagesFactory = $messagesFactory;
}
```

And then, where you want it :

```
$messages_model = $this->_messagesFactory->create();
$messages_model->load($the_id,'posts_id');
if(!$messages_model->getId()){
    echo "not found";
}
```

Comment: model load method is marked as deprecated. you should stick to using repository

Comment: yes, it is deprecated, but not all models have the relative repo. to avoid deprecated method you should use its resourceModel, you could access to ResourceModel with `->getResource()`, the right code is `$messages_model->getResource()->load($messages_model, $the_id, 'posts_id')`

Comment: @LucScu But now getResource() method also get deprecated. Is there any idea to load using ResourceModel?

Comment: @SiranjeeviKS just inject the resource model in your constructor

Answer (score 0):

Create Your function in Model and resource files.

```
public function loadByPostsId($field,$value)
{
    $id = $this->getResource()->loadByPostsId($field,$value);
    return $this->load($id);
}
```

In your resource Model

```
public function loadByPostsId($field,$value)
{
    $table = $this->getMainTable();
    $connection = $this->getConnection();
    $where = $connection->quoteInto("$field = ?", $value);
    $select = $connection->select()->from($table,array('posts_id'))->where($where);
    $id = $connection->fetchOne($select);
    return $id;
}
```

Comment: this solution also has some drawbacks. The main reason is model load method contain important code that initiate model load before/after events. https://nwdthemes.com/2017/06/10/magento-2-load-model-data-custom-field/

Comment: using load() method in model class is depreciated.