# Magento 2.1.1 - Display order subtotal in header

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

I have added the following to `minicart.phtml` for my theme and it doesn't work.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 

$subTotal = $cart->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
$grandTotal = $cart->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This above code will works on the page load, but will not work with magento2 ajax add to cart as it uses Knockout JS now.

For that you should use -

1. Override the magento class "*\Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart*" in your module and extend method "*getSectionData*"

```
    public function getSectionData()
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of Object Manager
        $priceHelper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data'); // Instance of Pricing Helper

        $totals = $this->getQuote()->getTotals();
        return [
            'summary_count' => $this->getSummaryCount(),
            'subtotal' => isset($totals['subtotal'])
                ? $this->checkoutHelper->formatPrice($totals['subtotal']->getValue())
                : 0,
            'subtotal_value' => isset($totals['subtotal'])
                ? $priceHelper->currency($totals['subtotal']->getValue(),true,false)
                : '',
            'possible_onepage_checkout' => $this->isPossibleOnepageCheckout(),
            'items' => $this->getRecentItems(),
            'extra_actions' => $this->layout->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\ShortcutButtons')->toHtml(),
            'isGuestCheckoutAllowed' => $this->isGuestCheckoutAllowed(),
        ];
    }
```

Here I have added a new cart param "*subtotal_value*" as the "*subtotal*" will return the price container span and it will display as TEXT using KO.
Here you have to use "*Object Manager Instance*" directly, as you wont be able to inject dependencies to the "*__construct*".

NOTE, there are few exception where we might need to use "*Object Manager Instance*" directly. In our case it is backward compatibility of constructor.

[ObjectManager Exception](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly#answer-117103)

2. Next, copy magento default theme "*/cart/minicart.phtml*" to your theme and add the KO codes.

```
ko text: getCartParam('subtotal_value')
```

Comment: Thanks. This definitely assisted me. However, subtotal if null doesn't display anything still. Any work around for that?

Comment: yes, in that case you can use the KO codes to show 0 or any text.


<!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
 <!-- ko text: getCartParam('subtotal_value') --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko ifnot: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
 <!-- ko text: "BASKET" --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->

Comment: Please vote it up if it helps you..!!

Comment: @user5762246 .. please mark this as the accepted answer if it really solves your issue.

Comment: @SandipanS thank you for the solution. Also note that that the knockout code (for example 'ko text: getCartParam('subtotal_value')'). Should be inside the 'data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'"' div, else it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

for grand total

```
<?php    $helper = $this->helper('\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart');
         echo $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data')->currency(number_format($helper->getQuote()->getGrandTotal(),2),true,false); ?>
```

**sub total**

```
<?php    $helper = $this->helper('\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart');
         echo $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data')->currency(number_format($helper->getQuote()->getSubtotal(),2),true,false); ?>
```

Comment: What's the proper way of utilizing that besides putting it in minicart.phtml file. I thought you had to utilize ko for dynamic stuff? Also, how would you get it to display 0.00 if carts empty?

Comment: the number format will do the trick for you  display `0.00`. for KO i didn't touch that yet