# Update Customer Data in Magento2 with custom attribute

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account

I want to **update the firstname of a customer** like this :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$customerFactory = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory');


$customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->setWebsiteId(1)->loadByEmail('cust123@gmail.com');

try {
    if(!empty($customer->getData('email')))
    {
        $customer->setFirstname('JokeAccount');
        $customer->save();
    } 
}
```

But the name of the customer doesn't change

Comment: Isn't your 2nd line conflicting with the 3rd one?

Answer (score 8):

I'm not entirely sure what's wrong with your code but here's how I did it a few weeks ago **using service contracts.** Also [please try to avoid using the ObjectManager directly](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/117098/2380)

```
protected $_customerRepoInterface;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepoInterface
) {
    $this->_customerRepoInterface = $customerRepoInterface;
}
```

Then in your code you can do:

```
// Second parameter is the website id
$customer = $this->_customerRepoInterface->get('cust123@gmail.com', 1);
// Update
$customer->setFirstname('JokeAccount');
$this->_customerRepoInterface->save($customer);
```

Comment: Hey dude this looks fine, my code already worked 50% just didn't mention to reindex... The customers name changed, but i have also some spezial customer field eg: textfield called "cusattr123" i want to fill it with $customer->setCusattr123('value'); but this didn't work.

Comment: @Ecoplan what if you try `$customer->setCustomAttribute('cusattr123','value');` ?

Comment: i tried it but it didn't work too

Comment: not working bro i did using helper but till not working...

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism in the above answer I am not able to get that where I am using object manager directly...please explain to me if I am doing anything wrong in detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

create a controller

```
   protected $_customerRepositoryInterface;

   public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
  ) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = customerRepositoryInterface;
  }
```

Now execute function here **reward_barcode** is custom attribute:

```
 public function execute()
  {
     $customerId = 2;
     if ($customerId) {

            $customer = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
            $customer->setCustomAttribute('reward_barcode', $barcode);
            $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->save($customer);

   }
   $this->messageManager->addSuccess( __('Your membership successfully updated.') );
}
```