# how to change customer session data in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, session, customer-session

after customer login, I want to change some of the session params like customer name. I do like this

```
$this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->setName("ddddddd");
```

also i tried this

```
$this->_customerSession->setName("ddddddd");
```

but it does not work.so how I can change the customer basic data, also how Magento handles session data? I think after every request the Magento set session data from database...hmmm am I going wrong?
is there anyone to talk about this?

> I want to change the customer name and this change should be staying
>   until the customer is login  ...lets to review my problem ... I have a
>   customer that can have sub customer (or may should I say, members)
>   when a sub customer want to login with his/her username and password I
>   check them and if they were correct I get parent customer and set it
>   login but I want to replace parent name with sub customer

Comment: yes please let me know I can help you!

Comment: please follow this URL : http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-set-unset-get-session/

Comment: thanks @sarveshDineshkumarPatel
your link adds another data to the session ... I need to change basically data like name

Comment: yes I can solve that too.  you need customer name change, am i right ?

Answer (score 1):

You can Set and get Customer session by using **Magento\Customer\Model\Session**

```
protected $customerSession;

public function __construct(   
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
){
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
}

$this->customerSession->setMyValue('test');
$this->customerSession->getMyValue();
```

Or by object manager.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$customerSession->setMyValue('test');
$customerSession->getMyValue();
```

Comment: i wanna change the basic data like customer name not set a new value to the session

Comment: I think for this you need to update customer data like name etc
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138286/update-customer-data-in-magento2-with-custom-attribute

Comment: no, it is not ...it save data forever but I want change session data not database data

Answer (score 1):

Please try to below code. But make sure you need to logged in.

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();  

$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$websiteId = $storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerRepository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface');

$customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    echo 'Customer Id: ' . $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId() . '<br/>';
    echo 'Customer Name: ' . $customerSession->getCustomer()->getName() . '<br/>';
    echo 'Customer Email: ' . $customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail() . '<br/>';

    $id = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId() ;

    $customer = $customerRepository->getById($id);
    $firstName ='Sarvesh 1';
    $lastName ='Patel 1';

    $customer->setFirstname($firstName);
    $customer->setLastname($lastName);
    $customerRepository->save($customer);
}

But Make sure after run this code logout and try again login. Hope it works!
```

Comment: thank but I think i could not descript my problem ... I want to change the customer name and this change should be staying until the customer is login  ...lets to review my problem ... I have a customer that can have sub customer (or may should I say, members) when a sub customer want to login with his/her username and password i check them and if they were correct i get parent customer and set it login but i want to replace parent name with sub customer

Comment: ok, you need to make a clear explanation. please share me more clear. thanks

Comment: ok, you need to make the first original name as save another session variable and then once you logout then set that name to your original one. because that logic you need to implement. Here I just give code to update the name. now you need to manage it on a session. If you can not I can explain you how. okay.

Comment: i think the best way is overriding the session class...thanks for your response

Comment: yes, thanks a lot. so please if it is a useful flag down and accept so this helps someone too. thanks, mate.

Comment: @ghdarvishani thanks mate.

Comment: me too @sarvesh Dineshkumar Patel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102928/discussion-between-sarvesh-dineshkumar-patel-and-gh-darvishani).