# Get product collection in product detail page in magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, php

I have created new phtml page in product/view folder

**xml**

```
 <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="other.products.category" template="product/view/relatedproduct.phtml" after="require-cookie"></block>
```

I need to load product listing in same category in product custom phtml page

I tried below code but its not working

```
$objectManagerr = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$curentProduct = $objectManager->getCurrentProduct();
echo $currentProduct->getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add bellow code in your block file.

for example `app/code/AR/CustomModule/Block/CustomBlock.php`

```
<?php
namespace AR\CustomModule\Block;
class CustomBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,       
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    )
    {       
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getCurrentCategory()
    {       
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
    }

    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {       
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
    }   

}
?>
```

Printing current product data in new phtml  file

```
if ($currentProduct = $block->getCurrentProduct()) {
    echo $currentProduct->getName();

}
```

Comment: You should never use object manager directly: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/117103/146

Comment: Updated ans pls check now

Answer (score 0):

You could try below code to get current product in custom phtml.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();    
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product'); 
$name  = $product->getName();
```