# How to delete a product in Magento-2 programmatically?

Tags: magento2, product, delete

I am trying to use below code but it is not working,

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$product->load($productID)->delete();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you try to delete product from fronend then you need to assign area for that.

Add following code to your class.

```
public function __construct(
    ........
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
) {
    ......
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->registry = $registry;
}
```

Following code is for deleting product.

```
$this->registry->register('isSecureArea', true);
// using sku
$this->productRepository->deleteById('Z62676');

// using product id
$product = $this->productRepository->getById(1);
$this->productRepository->delete($product);
```

Answer (score 4):

First, I suggest you try to [avoid using the ObjectManager directly](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/117098/2380)

Second, I reckon you should **use the `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface` service contrat** to delete a product:

```
protected $_productRepositoryInterface;

public function __construct(
     ...
     \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepositoryInterface, 
     ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_productRepositoryInterface = $productRepositoryInterface;
    ...
}
```

Then in your code you can do:

```
$product = $this->_productRepositoryInterface->getById($productID);
$this->_productRepositoryInterface->delete($product);
```

Note that if you have the sku of your product you can do it in one line:

```
$this->_productRepositoryInterface->deleteById($productSku);
```

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, you cannot delete product on the frontend area.

You need to force the SecureArea registry.

But if you check the `register` function, you see that you cannot override an existent key value. You need to **unregister** the key before register it.

```
/**
 * Register a new variable
 *
 * @param string $key
 * @param mixed $value
 * @param bool $graceful
 * @return void
 * @throws \RuntimeException
 */
public function register($key, $value, $graceful = false)
{
    if (isset($this->_registry[$key])) {
        if ($graceful) {
            return;
        }
        throw new \RuntimeException('Registry key "' . $key . '" already exists');
    }
    $this->_registry[$key] = $value;
}
```

**Solution based on other posts :**

Constructor :

```
public function __construct(
    ........
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
) {
    ......
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->registry = $registry;
}
```

Logic :

```
$this->registry->unregister('isSecureArea');
$this->registry->register('isSecureArea', true);
// using sku
$this->productRepository->deleteById('Z62676');

// using product id
$product = $this->productRepository->getById(1);
$this->productRepository->delete($product);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$product->load($productID)->delete();
```

Comment: This solution is not working for me,This is same code as what I was using to delete the product.

Comment: Any errors are display ?

Comment: Not any specific error, I found that we need to use $this->registry->register('isSecureArea', true);

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following script.

```
function deleteAllProducts($objectManager) {

$objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->register('isSecureArea', true);
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $productCollection->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();
$app_state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$app_state->setAreaCode('frontend');

foreach ($collection as $product){
    try {
        echo 'Deleted '.$product->getName().PHP_EOL;
        $product->delete();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Failed to remove product '.$product->getName() .PHP_EOL;
        echo $e->getMessage() . "\n" .PHP_EOL;
    }   
}      
}
```

Click here for detailed explanation. http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/delete-magento-2-products-programmatically/