# Get latest product programmatically in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

How to get Latest products in Magento 2 programmatically  in phtml file ?

Answer (score 4):

You can retrieve latest 10 products with the Magento 2 API or Repository

**Use API call (from javascript widget):**

```
GET http://<magento_host>/rest/V1/products?
```

And pass your search criteria as an argument.

```
searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=updated_at
searchCriteria[pageSize]=10
```

The full request :

```
GET http://<magento_host>/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=updated_at&searchCriteria[pageSize]=10
```

The documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/webapi/search-criteria.html

This prevents to manage the logic part which may change in the future Magento 2 release.

**Use Repository in you template:**

```
\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface::getList
```

The complete code :

```
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface as ProductRepository;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrder as SortOrder;

 /**
 * @var ProductRepository
 */
protected $productRepository;

public function __construct(
    ProductRepository $productRepository,
) {
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}

public function getLatestProducts($limit = 1)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroup $searchCriteriaGroup */
    $searchCriteriaGroup = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroup');
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria */

    $sortOrder = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrder');
    $sortOrder->setField('updated_at');
    $sortOrder->setDirection(SortOrder::SORT_DESC);

    $searchCriteria = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface');
    $searchCriteria->setFilterGroups([$searchCriteriaGroup]);
    $searchCriteria->setPageSize($limit);
    $searchCriteria->setSortOrders([$sortOrder]);

    return $this->productRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
}
```

And use dependancy injection to avoid objectManager

Answer (score 1):

Complete implementation of getting latest 10 product:

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$abstractProductBlock = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct');

$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $productCollection->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
            ->setPageSize(10)
            ->load();
?>
<div>
    <?php foreach ($collection as $product) :?>
        <div class="item-box">
            <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl(); ?>" >
                <span class="imgbx">
                    <img src="<?php echo $abstractProductBlock->getImage($product, 'latest_collection_list')->getImageUrl(); ?>" alt="<?php echo $product->getName(); ?>" />
                </span>
                <h3><?php echo $product->getName(); ?></h3>
                <span class="hm-price"><?php echo $abstractProductBlock->getProductPrice($product) ?></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach;  ?>
</div>
?>
```

Comment: That will definitely work but I suggest you try to avoid using the ObjectManager directly: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/117098/2380