# Change order status via PHP with Magento2

Tags: magento-2.0, order-status

Using Magento ver. 2.0.7
I am trying to use this code to change order to the status of "Processing", but i get an error, i think i am missing some prerequisite to call, but i can't figure it out.

> [25-Oct-2016 13:11:30 America/Detroit] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager' not found in /chroot/home/testplat/test.platinait.ca/html/pub/orderstatus.php on line 4

```
<?php

$orderId = 000000193;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')
                           ->load($orderId); 

$order->setState("processing")->setStatus("processing");

$order->save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can set order status like.

```
$orderId = 000000193;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order_status = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Mode\Order')->load($orderId);
$order_status->setStatus('processing');
$order_status->save();
```

Recommended to do this by creating custom module as well as passing the class in to constructor as a dependency.

Comment: i think i am missing a dependancy call because i get the same class missing message here too.

Comment: Yes, create a custom module and use this code there as a Yes, create a custom module and use this code there as a dependency..

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'getResource' method. Direct **load**, **save** and **delete** are deprecated in Mangeto >= 2.1.0.

Example :

```
$order_status->getResource()->save($order_status);
```

Comment: how does order_status know which order it is working on if your not pulling load($orderId) anymore? (or have i misinterpreted something here)

Comment: always use getResource for those methods. Or you can just inject OrderRepository and use get($id) and save($order) method

Comment: btw: aboute objectManager read this answere : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly