# Dynamically instanciate class with arguments

Tags: magento2, best-practice, class, object-manager

I am actually trying to instanciate a class dynamically with these arguments.
Here is the code I use in `class A`:

```
/** @var string $source */
$source = '\Foo\Bar\My\Class'; // Dynamic value that I am not aware because it is from other extensions

/** @var bool $isClassLoadable */
$isClassLoadable = $this->definedClasses->isClassLoadable($source);
if (!$isClassLoadable) {
    return false;
}

/** @var Model $model */
$model = $this->getModel(); // loaded model with data

/** @var \Magento\Framework\Simplexml\Config $config */
$config = $this->getConfig(); // loaded configuration with data

/** @var ProcessorInterface $processorInstance */
$processorInstance = $this->objectManager->create(
    $source,
    [
        $model,
        $config,
    ]
);
```

The `\Foo\Bar\My\Class` class code:

```
public function __construct(
    Model $model,
    Config $config
) {
    $this->model = $model;
    $this->config = $config;

    \Zend_Debug::dump($this->model->debug());
    \Zend_Debug::dump($this->config);
}
```

Here my two parameters are an empty model and an empty configuration.

**Questions**
- Is it a good practice to use `ObjectManager` to create class from a "string" ?
- If it is a "good practice" what is the way to keep my data between my `class A` and the `\Foo\Bar\My\Class` instanciation ?

---

**EDIT**
I am aware that using `ObjectManager` is a bad practice and `Factory` are here to avoid that but the `$source` is from a configuration and maybe third part extensions, I don't know his value. I hardcoded it for the purpose of my example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, [it's not a good practice to use the object manager](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/117103/146).
Use a factory instead.
To get an instance of `\Foo\Bar\My\Class` you will need to use an instance of `\Foo\Bar\My\ClassFactory` that will be automatically generated.

I assume that the code you listed in the question is part of a class.
you should have in your class this:

```
protected $fooBarFactory;
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Foo\Bar\My\ClassFactory $fooBarFactory,
    ....
) {
   .... 
   $this->fooBarFactory = $fooBarFactory;
    ....
}
```

Then you can instantiate your `\Foo\Bar\My\Class` like this:

```
$processorInstance = $this->fooBarFactory->create([
    'model' => $model,
    'config' => $config,
]);
```

The `create`method takes as parameter an array, and the keys in this array must match the constructor argument names in the class you are instantiating.
Your class accepts 2 parameters in the constructor called `$model` and `$config` hence the array keys `model` and `config`.
**[EDIT]**
In case your class acts as a factory you can use `ObjectManager`.
I think you should move the code that actually instantiates `$source` in a separate factory (that's not autogenerated) and you are allowed there to use the OM.
And you can inject that general factory in your class  and have something like this

```
$processorInstance = $this->customProcessorFactory->create(
    $source, 
    [
        'model' => $model,
        'config' => $config,
    ]
);
```

Comment: Hi, the thing I forgot to say that is the $source is from configuration and maybe third part extensions. I write it hardcoded here for the example. I am aware of the factory method but I can not use it here, I think. Or maybe do I have to manually add `Factory` to my `$source` string and mix the two methods ?

Comment: If I am right I can not inject my `$source` class to my `class A` depending on my edit informations

Comment: See my update to the answer. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: If I understand I create a class `CustomProcessorFactory` that I inject in my `Class A`. In that class I use the OM to create the source. So in my `Class A` I call `customProcessorFactory` as in you example which it is using the OM right ? If that is it I did not see what will change, that will just move my ObjectManager initial issue. Did I misunderstood your reasoning or maybe my example is not that clear ?

Comment: The idea was to use object manager only in classes that act as factories and do nothing else. If you move your `$source` instantiation to a separate class that just only instantiates it and does nothing else, you are off the hook. You are allowed to use OM. The effect will be the same but your code will be best practice compliant.

Comment: Oh OK right I understand, you answer my first question only, I though you're answering the second one too ! Do I have to correct my code and open a new question for the second one ?

Comment: The first part of my answer tells you how instantiate a certain class with specific parameters not with parameters that come from the DI container.  You have to pass an array to the OM or the factory method with your dependencies `[$model,$config]` just like you do, but you have to give array keys to your array in order to work properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49053/discussion-between-mattheo-geoffray-and-marius).