# Magento 2 class constructor

Tags: magento2, database, di, core-config-data

I have class in my module for **Magento 2**.
His constructor gets 2 parameters

```
class MyClass
{
    private $str1;
    private $str2;

    public function __construct(string $str1, string str2)
    {
        $this->str1 = $str1;
        $this->str2 = $str2;
    }
}
```

This parameters saved in **database** in `core_config_data` table.
I want use this class in other module classes, but i dont know how i can use DI for object transfer of this class in **constructors** others classes.
I can use for this `di.xml`?

Comment: Hard to understand the question, can you give more specific example?

Comment: `class ObserverClass extends Observer
    {
        public function __construct (MyClass $ myclass) {}
    }`

Comment: For example exist observer class and I want use my class in observer, like this. But dependency injection will not create this object, as dont know what parameters must get my class

Comment: I can create object through `$myclass = new MyClass($str1, $str2);` but this a bad practice in Magento

Comment: Please visit: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147366/dynamically-instanciate-class-with-arguments    this may help you