# Get currency rate by currency code

Tags: magento2, currency, currency-rates

I need to currency rate by currency code in magento 2.

```
$currency =  $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface');
$currencySymbol = $currency->getRate('USD');
```

I tried above code it returns fatal error.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon you should use `Magento\Directory\Model\Currency` class instead of `Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface`.

On top of that, I suggest you [never use the object manager directly](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/117098/2380) and use dependency injection instead.