# Magento 2 : Alternate Logo for Page Layout

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, page-layouts, home-page, logo

I'm developing Magento 2.1 application with two logos:

1. Light logo on the home page.
2. Dark logo for all other pages.

By default, theme uses dark logo. I've created a custom page layout for home page. In this layout, I attempted to override logo's `logo_file` argument. After flushing cache and all static assets, home page does not show logo defined in page layout.

### Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
...
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper" htmlClass="bmg-header-container bmg-header-inverse container">
            <!-- logo -->
            <container name="header-logo-container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header-logo-container">
                <referenceBlock name="logo">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/logo_dark_sm.png</argument>
                        <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">164</argument>
                        <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">59</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </referenceBlock>
            </container>
            <!-- /logo -->
            ...
</referenceContainer>
...
```

### Attempt 1 - Magento_Theme/page_layout/custom_home.xml

```
...
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
    <referenceContainer name="header-logo-container">
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/logo_light_sm.png</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </referenceContainer>
</referenceContainer>
...
```

### Attempt 2 - Magento_Theme/page_layout/custom_home.xml

```
...
<referenceContainer name="header-logo-container">
    <referenceBlock name="logo">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/logo_light_sm.png</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</referenceContainer>
...
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create helper to change logo dynamically

Override default.xml in your theme and add helper in **logo_file** argument

> Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="helper" helper="Vendor\Module\Helper\Data::getLogo"></argument>
```

In your helper, you can get logo based on current url like this.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $_request;

    public function __construct
    (
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    ) {
        $this->_request = $request;
    }

    public function getLogo()
    {
        if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'cms_index_index') {
            $logo =  'images/logo_light_sm.png';
        } else {
            $logo = 'images/logo_dark_sm.png';
        }

        return $logo;
    }
}
```

Comment: That did the trick! Could you please explain why I should not use the objectManager directly?

Comment: There are several reasons. The code will work, but it is best practice to not reference the ObjectManager class directly. Please refer this for more details https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/117098

Comment: I am using multi website and for the Korea site i tried above way but getting wrong image src path (it includes src path site_url/pub/static/version/en_US/...) due to which logo is not showing ...so i overrided logo.phtml file into my theme and used helper into this which works fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

The better way to do this will be using helper function.
in your *`Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`* you can pass argument for logo like this-

```
<argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="helper" helper="Namespace\ModuleName\Helper\Data::getLogoImage"></argument>
```

and then in your helper file you can return logo based on current url, Your helper file-

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $objectManager
)
{

    $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
}        

public function getLogoImage()
    {

        $fullAction =  $this->_objectManager->getFullActionName();;
        if($fullAction == 'cms_index_index')
        {
            $logo =  'images/logo_light_sm.png';
        }
        else
        {
            $logo = 'images/logo_dark_sm.png';
        }
        return $logo;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried, this is working for me very well.

**Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/logo_light_sm.png</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

This solution is no better than creating helper class?

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have given configuration to upload Light and dark logo, you can see here:-

[image]

**System.xml:-**

```
<field id="logo_homepage" translate="label" type="image" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" >
                    <label>Logo For Homepage</label>
                    <backend_model>YourNamespace\YourModule\Model\Config\Backend\Image</backend_model>
                    <base_url type="media" scope_info="1">logo</base_url>
                </field>
                 <field id="logo_otherthan_homepage" translate="label" type="image" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" >
                    <label>Logo For Other Pages</label>
                    <backend_model>YourNamespace\YourModule\Model\Config\Backend\Image</backend_model>
                    <base_url type="media" scope_info="1">logo</base_url>
                    <comment>Logo except homepage.</comment>
 </field>
```

And then overrided logo.phtml file into my theme. used helper into this .phtml file to set uploaded dark and light logo of the configuration into the src of logo.phtml.

**YourNamespace\YourModule\Model\Config\Backend\Image.php:-**

```
<?php

namespace YourNamespace\YourModule\Model\Config\Backend;

class Image extends \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Image
{
    /**
     * The tail part of directory path for uploading
     *
     */
    const UPLOAD_DIR = 'logo'; // Folder save image

    /**
     * Return path to directory for upload file
     *
     * @return string
     * @throw \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    protected function _getUploadDir()
    {
        return $this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($this->_appendScopeInfo(self::UPLOAD_DIR));
    }

    /**
     * Makes a decision about whether to add info about the scope.
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _addWhetherScopeInfo()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for allowed extensions of uploaded files.
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    protected function _getAllowedExtensions()
    {
        return ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'svg'];
    }


}
```

**YourNamespace\YourModule\Helper\Data.php:-**

```
<?php

namespace YourNamespace\YourModule\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

/**
 * Created by Carl Owens (carl@partfire.co.uk)
 * Company: PartFire Ltd (www.partfire.co.uk)
 **/
class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
     */
    private $httpContext;

    /**
     * Scope config
     *
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

   
    const LOGO_HOMEPAGE = 'section/group/logo_homepage';

    const LOGO_OTHERTHAN_HOMEPAGE = 'section/group/logo_otherthan_homepage';

    const LOGO_FOLDER_NAME = 'logo';

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_request = $request;
    }


    


    public function getLogo()
    {
        $scope = ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;

        $folderName = self::LOGO_FOLDER_NAME;

        $logoUrl = '';

        if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'cms_index_index') {
            $logo = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::LOGO_HOMEPAGE, $scope);
        } else {
            $logo = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::LOGO_OTHERTHAN_HOMEPAGE, $scope);
        }

        if (!empty($logo)) {
            $storeLogoPath = $logo;

            $path = $folderName . '/' . $storeLogoPath;

            $logoUrl = $this->_urlBuilder
                ->getBaseUrl(['_type' => \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA]) . $path;
        }
        return $logoUrl;
    }
}
```

**app\design\frontend\ThemnNamespace\Themname\Magento_Theme\templates\html\header\logo.phtml:-**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * @var \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo $block
 */
?>
<?php
    $helper = $this->helper('YourNamespace\YourModule\Helper\Data');
    $logoSrc = $helper->getLogo()!='' ? $helper->getLogo() : $block->getLogoSrc() ;
?>
<?php $storeName = $block->getThemeName() ? $block->getThemeName() : $block->getLogoAlt();?>
<span data-action="toggle-nav" class="action nav-toggle"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Toggle Nav') ?></span></span>
<a
    class="logo"
    href="<?= $block->getUrl('') ?>"
    title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $storeName ?>"
    aria-label="store logo">
    <img src="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $logoSrc ?>"
         title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getLogoAlt()) ?>"
         alt="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getLogoAlt()) ?>"
         <?= $block->getLogoWidth() ? 'width="' . $block->getLogoWidth() . '"' : '' ?>
         <?= $block->getLogoHeight() ? 'height="' . $block->getLogoHeight() . '"' : '' ?>
    />
</a>
```