# Remove customer_account_navigation-reports block for specific customer group in magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer-group

I want to remove customer_account_navigation-reports block from customer account on the frontend for specific customer group i.e. Distributor

How can I do this?

Comment: This seems similar requirement - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/211137/only-show-link-in-account-navigation-to-specific-customer-groups

Comment: Thanks @Evince. can you please tell me how to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the soution.

1. Create a custom module Abweb_Customer.
2. Create `registration.php` in Abweb/Customer and `module.xml` in Abweb/Customer/etc folder.
3. Create `di.xml` in Abweb/Customer/etc folder with following code.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" ?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Index" type="Abweb\Customer\Controller\Account\Index" />
   </config>
   ```
4. Create `Index.php`in Abweb\Customer\Controller\Account folder with following code.

   ```
   <?php
   namespace Abweb\Customer\Controller\Account;
   use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
   use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

   class Index extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Index
   {
   /**
   * @var PageFactory
   */
   protected $resultPageFactory;
   protected $customersession;

   public function __construct(
   Context $context,
   \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customersession,       
   PageFactory $resultPageFactory
   ) {
   parent::__construct($context,$resultPageFactory);
   $this->customersession=$customersession;
   $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
   }
   public function execute()
   {
   if($this->customersession->isLoggedIn())
   {
       $cgid = $this->customersession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();  // get Customer Group Id
       $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
       $layout = $resultPage->getLayout();

       if($cgid!="10") // Distributor Customer Group
       {
           $block = $layout->getBlock('customer_account_navigation-reports'); // block name
           $layout->unsetElement('customer_account_navigation-reports'); //remove block
           return $resultPage;
       } else {
           return $resultPage;
       }

   }
   }
   }
   ```
5. Done. Now all you have to do is change the customer-group code and block name that you want to remove.