# Show different logo when logged in

Tags: magento2, css, xml

How to show different logo when the user is logged in?

Comment: follow [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/176303/20064) and in helper check customer is login or not then pass logo path as per your need

Comment: can you give me more details please

Comment: what more details you need? if you follow that answer you will achieve what you need with little modifications

Comment: so i replace  <arguments>
          <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/logo.png</argument>
          <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">192</argument>
          <!--<argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">50</argument>-->
         </arguments> with <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="helper" helper="Namespace\ModuleName\Helper\Data::getLogoImage"></argument>
where i can find helper file?

Comment: you have to create a custom module for this or need to add that helper function in any existing module

Comment: i understand the logic but not a simple as it see, it's like i gave you 4 wheels and ask you to build a car

Comment: Sorry friend I am little bit busy, will surely help you when I get some time.

Answer (score 3):

You can set different logo while customer is logged in using a helper method, You have to [Create a custom module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122287/how-to-create-simple-module-in-magento-2) for this.

In your layout you have to pass helper method for logo path,By adding below code in file

> Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="helper" helper="Namespace\ModuleName\Helper\Data::getLogoImage"></argument>
```

After that in your modules helper file you have to add below code

```
<?php

    namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Helper;

    class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
    {
        protected $_request;
        protected $_session;

        public function __construct
        (
            \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session
        ) {
            $this->_request = $request;
            $this->_session = $session;
        }

        public function getLogoImage()
        {
            if ($this->_session->isLoggedIn()) {
                $logo =  'path/to/logo/for/logged_in/customer.png';
            } else {
                $logo = 'path/to/logo/for/guest/customer.png';
            }

            return $logo;
        }
    }
```

**Note:** Change Namespace and ModuleName based on your custom Module

Comment: What if the logo is set in the admin?

Comment: @BenCrook in that case we have to replace logo path with storeConfig value

Comment: is there a step by step procedure easy to use to achieve this objective?

Comment: @Piyush Can you please explain how we can call it from logo.phtml or through block, and where to define this argument inside the block or some refrenceBlock? Thankyou

Comment: @Piyush I have done it through using the helper object in logo.phtml file.