# Update custom column data in quote table Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, quote, custom-quote

I inserted a custom column in quote table like this:

```
if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {
          $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
              $setup->getTable('quote'),
              'custom_column',
              [
                  'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                  'nullable' => true,
                  'comment' => 'Custom Column',
             ]
          );
        }
```

The custom column was successfully created, and added to every single row in quote table with null value, but the problem is, i don't know how to update the custom column data in the quote table by using only quote id

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is to fill in this field in the quote model and save it using the Repository:

```
class QuoteUpdater
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository
     */
    protected $quoteRepository;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
    ) {
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    }

    public function updateQuoteData($quoteId, int $customData)
    {
        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($quoteId); // Get quote by id
        $quote->setData('custom_column', $customData); // Fill data
        $this->quoteRepository->save($quote); // Save quote
    }
}
```

Comment: How to get the $customData in this repository if it's a form field in addtocart.phtml?

Comment: greate job using service contract!

Comment: The `\Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface` interface should be injected, instead of injecting the `\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository` which is not backwards compatible.

Answer (score 2):

To set data in quote table, use below code -

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$quoteId = 10;
$customColumnValue = 1; 
$quote = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote')->load($quoteId);
$quote->setCustomColumn($customColumnValue);
$quote->save();
```

Here replace $quoteId variable with your quote ID .

Comment: You should [not use the ObjectManager directly](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly)

Comment: Yes, this is just for an example. We should Inject Object Manager in Constructor first then can use its object in method.
1. declare object:
      private $_objectManager;
2. Inject in constructor and initialize :

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager
) 
{
    $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
}

Comment: Unless its in a plugin..