# How to update custom column value in quote_item table magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom, quoteitem, column

> Actually i created custom column in quote_item and trying to update the value once
>   product added to the cart programmatically magento2  custom module
>   using Model.
>
> If Anyone have idea please guide me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: i tried this link but not working https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177372/update-custom-column-data-in-quote-table-magento-2

Comment: You need this for only frontend area or want  for all area.

Comment: @AmitBera yes i am doing  it for frontend area only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use implement [**extension attribute for this field**](https://store.fooman.co.nz/blog/an-introduction-to-extension-attributes.html) at here.

See how to use Extension attribute. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html

Make ***your field as an extension attribute of data interface*** `Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface`

Create  `extension_attributes.xml` at `app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/etc/`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface">
        <attribute code="{YOUR_FIELD_NAME}" type="{FIELD_TYPE}">
        </attribute>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

After that you to set this field value using  event `checkout_cart_product_add_after`