# Magento 2 phtml get store view being viewed

Tags: magento2, store-view

In Magento 2 I have a phtml file I am trying to get what store view is currently being seen by the website visitor. 
However it does not seem to work.
I dont want to have to create a whole module or plugin .

```
if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() > '1')
{
      echo "you are 1";
}
elseif (Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() > '2')
{
     echo "you are 2";
}
 else
{
   echo "you are not 1 or 2";
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can fetch the current store id and the store name in phtml file (using ObjectManager) like below :

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
$storeManager  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$storeID       = $storeManager->getStore()->getId(); 
$storeName     = $storeManager->getStore()->getName();
```

you can use this `$storeID` according to your condition :

```
if ($storeID > '1')
{
    // your logic
}
```

However, this is not a proper approach. A much cleaner way would be to use a block or a helper

Comment: It's considered bad practice to use ObjectManager this way.
See [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly) for more detail.

Answer (score 6):

you can inject the `Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterf‌​ace` in your constructor to get the store view in block and send to phtml.

```
protected $_storeManagerInterface;

public function __construct(
     \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterf‌​ace $storeManagerInterface
    )
{
    $this->_storeManagerInterface = $storeManagerInterface;

}
```

Then in your code you can do:

```
$currentStore = $this->_storeManagerInterface->getStore();
$currentStoreId = $currentStore->getId();
```

based on store id you can write a condition.

Comment: please check it and let me know

Comment: So do I put the public_function in the top of the contact.phtml page or ..? Because when I put it in to the file it makes the page load blank with no errors.

Comment: The class `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` already includes an instance of `Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterf‌​ace`, which should be available to all child block classes. It is a private property though and won't be available in the template without creating creating a public function to return it. This can't be accomplished from within the template.

Comment: _storeManager in Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template is a protected property not (at least in 2.3.4), so it should work out of the box.