# Get customer name from customer id using object manager

Tags: magento2, customer, object-manager

I try to use object manager to retrieve customer first name and last name using customer id like this:

```
$customer = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface')->getById($customerId);
print_r($customer->getFirstName());
```

unfortunately, it prints empty string.

Comment: did you check your customerid is right or not? if invalid then throws error.

Comment: Note a good thing to use the object manager. Its not a good practice and Magento advices to not use it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try below code :

```
$customerID = 10; // your customer-id
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')
            ->load($customerID);
$customerFirstName = $customerObj->getFirstname();
```

Answer (score 4):

**By ObjectManager:**

```
$customerID = 1; //Customer ID
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($customerID);
echo $customer->getFirstname(); //Print Customer First Name
echo $customer->getLastname(); //Print Customer Last Name
```

**By Factory Method:**

```
protected $_customers;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customers
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_customers = $customers;
    ...
}

public function getCustomer($customerId)
{
    //Get customer by customerID
    $customer = $this->_customers->load($customerId);
    echo $customer->getFirstname(); //Print Customer First Name
    echo $customer->getLastname(); //Print Customer Last Name
}

public function getCollection()
{
    //Get customer collection
    return $this->_customers->getCollection();
}
```

Note: Don't use objectManager instance directly in files more details here: [To use or not to use the ObjectManager directly?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve like this also:

```
   <?php  



namespace Mastering\Itdesire\Block\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    protected $_customer;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
    )
    {
        $this->_customer = $customer;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

     public function getCustomer()
    {
        $customerId = '189'; //You customer ID
        $customer = $this->_customer->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('eq' => $customerId));
        echo "Customer Firstname:".$customer->getFirstname();
        echo "Customer Lastname:".$customer->getLastname();
    }

}
```

Hope, This will help you some extend.

Answer (score 2):

**Try following code:**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

try{

    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php'; 

    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
    $customerRepository = $obj->create(\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface::class);

    $customerId = 1;
    $customer = $customerRepository->getById($customerId);

    if ($customer->getId()) {
        echo "Customer Firstname: " . $customer->getFirstname() . "<br/>";
        echo "Customer Lastname: " . $customer->getLastname();
    }

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

OR

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository 
){
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
}

public function getCustomerDetails()
{
    $customerId = 1;
    $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
    if ($customer->getId()) {
        echo $customer->getFirstname();
        echo $customer->getLastname();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

/**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customers
     */
     protected $_customers;

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customers)
{
 $this->_customers = $customers;
}

public function getCustomer($customerId)
{
  //Get customer by customerID
  return $this->_customers->load($customerId);
}
public function getCustomerName(){
   $customer = $this->getCustomer($cutomerID);
   //return $customer->getLastname(); // for last name
   return $customer->getFirstname(); // for first name
}
```