# How to modify delete method using objectManager

Tags: magento2, best-practice

I have found the some extension from Amasty and here is the snipped code to delete the data using `objectManager` :

```
public function deleteBy($methodId)
{
    /**
     * @var \Amasty\ShippingTableRates\Model\ResourceModel\Rate $resource
     */
    $resource = $this->_objectManager->get('Amasty\ShippingTableRates\Model\ResourceModel\Rate');
    $resource->deleteBy($methodId);
}
```

I know that from using `objectManager` is not the recommended way from [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/object-manager.html) and [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly).

The problem using `objectManager` when I try to change the behavior of import csv file on this class using `Plugin` it breaks the delete function, and every time admin try to delete always shows this error :

> array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php on
>   line 146

Here is my Plugin :

```
use Amasty\ShippingTableRates\Model\Rate as RateAmasty;


class Rate extends RateAmasty
{
    /**
     * Change total number column
     * We change the hidden column == 0 because additional column
     */
    const COL_NUMS = 20;
    const HIDDEN_COLUMNS = 0;

    /**
     * index for generated columns
     */
    const NUM_ZIP_FROM = 16;
    const NUM_ZIP_TO = 17;

    /**
     * import csv file
     */
    public function aroundImport(RateAmasty $subject, \Closure $proceed,$methodId, $fileName)
    {

        $err = [];

        $fp = $this->_file->fileOpen($fileName, 'r');
        $methodId = intval($methodId);
        if (!$methodId) {
            $err[] = __('Specify a valid method ID.');
            return $err;
        }

        $countryCodes = $this->_helper->getCountries();
        $countryNames = $this->_helper->getCountries(true);
        $typeLabels = $this->_helper->getTypes(true);

        $data = [];

        $currLineNum = 0;
        while (($line = $this->_file->fileGetCsv($fp, self::MAX_LINE_LENGTH, ',', '"')) !== false) {
            $currLineNum++;

            if ($currLineNum == 1) {
                continue;
            }

            if ((count($line) + self::HIDDEN_COLUMNS) != self::COL_NUMS) {
                $err[] = 'Line #' . $currLineNum . ': warning, expected number of columns is ' . self::COL_NUMS;
                if (count($line) > self::COL_NUMS) {
                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($line) - self::COL_NUMS; $i++) {
                        unset($line[self::COL_NUMS + $i]);
                    }
                }

                if (count($line) < self::COL_NUMS) {
                    for ($i = 0; $i < self::COL_NUMS - count($line); $i++) {
                        $line[count($line) + $i] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            $dataZipFrom = $this->_helper->getDataFromZip($line[self::ZIP_FROM]);
            $dataZipTo = $this->_helper->getDataFromZip($line[self::ZIP_TO]);
            $line[self::NUM_ZIP_FROM] = $dataZipFrom['district'];
            $line[self::NUM_ZIP_TO] = $dataZipTo['district'];

            for ($i = 0; $i < self::COL_NUMS - self::HIDDEN_COLUMNS; $i++) {
                $line[$i] = str_replace(["\r", "\n", "\t", "\\", '"', "'", "*"], '', $line[$i]);
            }

            $countries = [''];
            if ($line[self::COUNTRY]) {
                $countries = explode(',', $line[self::COUNTRY]);
            } else {
                $line[self::COUNTRY] = '0';
            }

            $line = $this->_setDefaultLineValues($line);

            $typesData = $this->_prepareLineTypes($line, $err, $currLineNum, $typeLabels);
            $line = $typesData['line'];

            foreach ($countries as $country) {
                if ($country == 'All') {
                    $country = 0;
                }

                if ($country && empty($countryCodes[$country])) {
                    if (in_array($country, $countryNames)) {
                        $countryCodes[$country] = array_search($country, $countryNames);
                    } else {
                        $err[] = 'Line #' . $currLineNum . ': invalid country code ' . $country;
                        continue;
                    }

                }
                $line[self::COUNTRY] = $country ? $countryCodes[$country] : '0';

                $statesData = $this->_prepareLineStates($line, $err, $currLineNum, $country, $methodId);
            }// countries
        } // end while read
        fclose($fp);

        if (isset($statesData['data_index'])) {
            $err = $this->returnErrors($statesData['data'], $methodId, $currLineNum, $statesData['err']);
        }

        return $err;

    }

}
```

My question is how to modify this delete method to the best way in magento 2 ? Since I'm still new to this big platform and still don't know how.

Comment: Can you post your Plugin here?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh Updated

Comment: Don't need to extend `Amasty\ShippingTableRates\Model\Rate`. Should remove it.

Comment: ya But the error still exist @KhoaTruongDinh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to you `ObjectManager`which is not recommended way to do that.
There are several options you can choose :

1. `Amasty\ShippingTableRates\Model\Rate` create a constructor in you class and make it accessible using your local variable like `protected _rate;`
2. Find the `interface` class in the Api Folder in the module directory usually it will have name like `RateInterface`. and create your constructor in your class and place additional argument just like in the step 1.
3. If you don't find `Interface` class then you can pass directly call the `Amasty\ShippingTableRates\Model\Rate` to your constructor class.

Hopefully this will helps others