# Magento 2 : How to write logs from a phtml file in a theme

Tags: magento2.2, log

How to write logs in **var/log/whatever_file** from a phtml file which belongs to my custom theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Wrong way :**

1. Using classes and objectmanager directly in your phtml

**Good way :**

Find the .xml that outputs your .phtml file. This can be find in the same Magento Module within the folder `'view/frontend/layout'` where you find the .phtml file. You will find a Block somewhere with a class and a template much like this :
**(i will use this as an example)**

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.sku" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" after="product.info.type">
```

This has a `class` and a `template`. What you want to do is add functionality to that class which logs it for you.

Now let's create a new PHP file that we will use instead of this one.

1. create a basic module
   [How to create a basic module](http://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-module/)
2. add a `di.xml` within your etc/ folder in your new module

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
> <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" type="YourVendor\YourModule\Block\Product\View\Description"/>
> </config>
> ```

*(is in a 'qoute' instead of a 'code' because stackexchange won't show the code for some reason otherwise)*

Here we define that we want to replace this class with our own whenever this is used. If we just want to replace it for that 1 instance you can adjust the class in your layout xml that is reponsible for creating the block and adjust the class there.
[Common layout tasks](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html)

Now we need to create our PHP class :

```
app/code/yourvendor/yourmodule/Block/Product/View/Description.php

<?php 
namespace yourvendor/yourmodule/Block/Product/View;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description as MagentoDescription;
use yourvendor/yourmodule/Logger/YourLogger;

class Description extends MagentoDescription{

    protected $_logger;

public function __construct (
... ,
YourLogger $logger){
$this->_logger = $logger;
}


// add new function to log things (or do anything)

public function addLogCritical(\Exception $e){

$this->_logger->critical('an error has occured :' . $e);

}

}
```

Here we added our own logger function and used a new logger class.

Now we will make our logger class (that we can use anywhere from now on) to create or own custom file.

```
YourVendor/YourModule/Logger/YourLogger.php

<?php
namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Logger;

use Monolog\Logger as MonologLogger;

class YourLogger extends MonologLogger
{

}
```

We leave this empty but we use the Monolog Logger. We can add function in here later if needed.

Now create a Handler

```
YourVendor/YourModule/Logger/Handler.php

<?
namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Logger;

use Magento\Framework\Logger\Handler\Base;

class Handler extends Base {
    /**
     * Logging level
     * @var int
     */
    protected $loggerType = Logger::DEBUG;

    /**
     * File name
     * @var string
     */
    protected $fileName = '/var/log/customfolder/customname.log';
}
```

And now we bind them in our `YourVendor/YourModule/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="YourVendor\YourModule\Logger\Handler">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="filesystem" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="YourVendor\YourModule\Logger\YourLogger">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">DesignitSync</argument>
            <argument name="handlers"  xsi:type="array">
                <item name="system" xsi:type="object">YourVendor\YourModule\Logger\Handler</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

And done! Now you have your own custom logger the good way.

You can use your new public function in your phtml file with `$block->addLogCritical('error message');`

Comment: I have added the frontend/di.xml code , it wasn't showing for some odd reason. Had to put it in a quote instead of a code in the stackexchange editor

Comment: I hope you learned a lot about what the difference is between bad practices and good practices in Magento 2

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a new file for log, use the following code.

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Your text message');
```

If you want to add a log in the existing log file of Magento, use the following code.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$logger = $objectManager->get("Psr\Log\LoggerInterface");
$logger->debug('debug log example'); // add logs in debug.log
$logger->info('system log example'); // add logs in system.log
```

Comment: Thanks! How to you put it in the debug.log file instead ?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: objectmanager? Really? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly

Comment: @SwAt.Be What's the recommended way ?

Comment: I have posted it in an answer beneath , it took me longer then 2 seconds to reply but someone here is out for points @DineshYadav instead of giving a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code to write custom code in .phtml file

**for Magento 2.4.2 before version use this**

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/customlog.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Custom message');
```

**for Magento 2.4.2 or after version use this**

```
$writer = new \Laminas\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/customlog.log');
$logger = new  \Laminas\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('text message');
```

**for Magento 2.4.3 version use this**

```
$writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/customlog.log');
$logger = new \Zend_Log();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('text message');
```