# Create link to internal page from its url key

Tags: magento2, theme, phtml, url-key

How should I create the link to internal page in a template file ?

For instance, I have a **subcategory** which **URL key** is `education`, how should it be called in my **phtml** file to get the page `http://my.website.com/education.html` ?

I'm currently using this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $block->getUrl('education.html') ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are trying to get subcategory url with url key . here is solution - 
Define objectmanager in your block-

```
$category = $block->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')
->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('url_key',$URL_KEY)->getFirstItem();

 $url = $category->getUrl(); 

?>"
```

use it like this

Comment: Thanks for the reply but using _objectManager is not recommended. You can read this post about it: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly