# Get cost of Handling Fee in phtml file

Tags: magento2

How can I retrieve the cost of fixed delivery (Handling Fee) that is set in administration, in one of my phtml files, so I can show the value of it?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to get the flat rate shipping amount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get flat rate price by using below code in phtml:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$flatratePrice = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('carriers/flatrate/price');
```

You can inject the scopeconfiginterface to block and then use directly in your phtml if needed.

Comment: Thanks. However, I need to get the handling fee value, this returns the price. Any ideas? Tried changing 'price' to 'handlingfee' and doesnt work :/

Comment: Ok got it, changed price to handling_fee and it works

Comment: Wait I am updating my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use directly the **objectManager** is a bad practice ! `\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()`, Read [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly)

1. `app/code/{Vendor}/{ModuleName}/Helper/Data.php`

   ```
   public function getConfig($config_path)
   {
       return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                  $config_path,
                  \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
              );
   }
   ```
2. ```
   $flatratePrice = $this->helper('{Vendor}\{ModuleName}\Helper\Data')->getConfig('carriers/flatrate/price');

   $flatrateHandlingFee = $this->helper('{Vendor}\{ModuleName}\Helper\Data')->getConfig('carriers/flatrate/handling_type');
   ```