# How to display stock information to logged in customer only in Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, customer, stock-status

I want to display stock only to logged in customers. can you guide me how can I do? [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below code, it will hide stock sku information from the product details page for not logged in user.

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Anshu_Custom" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog" />
            <module name="Magento_Customer" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/registration.php**

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(
    ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Anshu_Custom',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/etc/frontend/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="add_layout_handles" instance="Anshu\Custom\Observer\AddHandles" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/Observer/AddHandles.php**

```
<?php

namespace Anshu\Custom\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;

class AddHandles implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_customerSession;

    public function __construct(CustomerSession $_customerSession)
    {
        $this->_customerSession = $_customerSession;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();

        if (!$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn())
        {
            $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('customer_logged_out');
        }
    }
}
```

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/view/frontend/layout/customer_logged_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.stock.sku" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

This will give you some idea and you can modify it according to your requirement.

Comment: This code is not working

Comment: I have checked in 2.2.6 on the product page and it works for me. Check in your vanilla Magento. May be compatibility issue with the theme.

Comment: code is working now. i want to disable only stock then how can I Do?

Comment: If I am correct then stock and sku are coming from the same template (Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml), you need to create a separate template from one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

    $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

    if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {

       $_product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getQty();

    }
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the response, I am using custom theme. Can you guide me  where I can use this code and in which file?

Comment: Please, use Mukesh answer , here why https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly

Comment: Don't use object Manager directly, it is not recommended Magento practice.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use **$objectManager** directly. Use below code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$customerFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory');

if($customerFactory->create()->isLoggedIn()) {
    $product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getQty();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain me please where I can use this code?

Comment: @kiran in your phtml file

Comment: @kiran like this

 like this      $stockQty = $product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getQty();

     echo $stockQty;

Comment: In which file, I use this code?

Comment: @kiran in which page you want to display this ?

Comment: Every Product page, Please see attached screenshot.

Comment: I attached one more screenshot, can we display stock each product only for logged customer.

Comment: package/theme/Magento_Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml

after this code
 
$block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>

Comment: app\design\frontend\Solwin\freego\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\list.phtml path is correct

Comment: yes correct. Please clear cache after changes

Comment: I tried but it's not working

Comment: Don't use object Manager directly, it is not recommended Magento practice.