# Magento 2: Only display Out of Stock products if logged in

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1

I am building a B2B M2 website using open source 2.3.1 which will have specific customer groups. I want to display out of stock products but only when logged in. When logged out I do not want people able to see out of stock items. Is this possible? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This link might give you an approach https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/243317/how-to-display-stock-information-to-logged-in-customer-only-in-magento-2