# Get product image in Reviews

Tags: magento2, php

I would like to get product image in reviews, can anyone help with some advice on how to do it?

Currently I have magento reviews - 
[image]

And what I would like to get is like this - 
[image]

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2):

In your custom theme create directory as

Magento_Review/templates/review.phtml

In review.phtml file write following  code

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product


    $helperImport = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');

    $imageUrl = $helperImport->init($product, 'product_page_image_small')
                    ->setImageFile($product->getSmallImage()) // image,small_image,thumbnail
                    ->resize(380)
                    ->getUrl();

<img src="<?php echo $imageUrl  ?>" />
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: It works, but is it possible to do this without using objectmanager? Thank you a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

**Don't use ObjectManager directly in phtml files [Learn More](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly)**

**1) Override class `Magento\Review\Block\Product\Review`**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Review\Block\Product\Review" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\Override\Review" />
</config>
```

**2) Create `Review.php`**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Product/Override/Review.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Product\Override;

class Review extends \Magento\Review\Block\Product\Review
{
    protected $imageHelperFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory $imageHelperFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->imageHelperFactory = $imageHelperFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $collectionFactory, $data);
    }

    public function getProductImage()
    {
        $product = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('product');
        $imageUrl = $this->imageHelperFactory->create()
            ->init($product, 'product_base_image')->getUrl();

        return $imageUrl;
    }
}
```

**3) Now in `review.phtml` call `getProductImage()` function to get image url**

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Review/templates/review.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var \Magento\Review\Block\Product\Review $block */
?>
<div>
    <img src="<?= $block->getProductImage() ?>" />
</div>
<div id="product-review-container" data-role="product-review"></div>
<?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Review/js/process-reviews": {
                "productReviewUrl": "<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeUrl($block->getProductReviewUrl())) ?>",
                "reviewsTabSelector": "#tab-label-reviews"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: hi @prince patel, can you look into this issue please, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/253672/update-attribute-option-label-with-id-magento2

Comment: @PrincePatel Hey, thank you a lot for your help, it works, but question - how can I call it not inside review.phtml file but inside list.phtml file? Because if I call it inside review.phtml file it works, but if I call it inside list.phtml file it says "unknown"

Comment: @help for `list.phtml` you need to override class  `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct`

Comment: @PrincePatel Can you maybe please update your answer and show how to override that class? I keep getting unknown. P.S. I need to display image in `module-review/frontend/templates/product/view/list.phtml`, is it really the right file you are saying that I need to override?

Comment: @help This question is about show product image on the review tab. Please ask another question for show image on the list page to keep clean and clear comments on this queue :)

Answer (score 0):

at Magento_Review\templates\form.phtml add this code :

```
<?php 
foreach ($block->getProductInfo()->getMediaGallery('images') as $image) {
    $imageUrl = $block->getProductInfo()->getMediaConfig()->getMediaUrl($image['file']);
}
?>
```

and then you can show the image like this :

```
<img class="product-image" src="<?= $imageUrl ?>" />
```

Magento ver. 2.3.1