# Datasheet from product images gallery in modal popup

Tags: magento2.3

I would like to show the product data sheet in a modal popup. I intend to add the data sheet to the product image gallery, keep it hidden and then recall it in the popup.

Create the modal popup is not difficult, I need help only to display the image product.

To do this I created a new image attribute "datasheet", so I would like to use a similar code to show the attributes but in this case it will shows the datasheet image and that it can dynamically change for configurable products.

Can you help me?

Comment: show your code that you tried.

Comment: Hi, I used this code to call image: <img class="col data datasheet" 
data-th="<?= $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('datasheet')->getStoreLabel(); ?>" 
src="<?= $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('datasheet')->getImageUrl(); ?>" />
Show me popup blank

Comment: try this code may be help you : -- `<img class="col data datasheet" data-th="<?= $product->getResource()->getAttribute('datasheet')->getFrontend()->getValue($product); ?>" src="<?= $product->getResource()->getAttribute('datasheet')->getFrontend()->getValue($product)->getImageUrl(); ?>" />`

Comment: Hi Mohit, the code show error: Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined variable: product in

Comment: `<img class="col data datasheet" data-th="<?= $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('datasheet')->getFrontend()->getValue($product); ?>" src="<?= $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('datasheet')->getFrontend()->getValue($product)->getImageUrl(); ?>" />`

Comment: Hi, again an error: Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined variable: product in

Comment: Hi, I solved  follow some step in this post: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/253668/12071 , edit with my data and it works