# How to load database table records into the Magento CMS page

Tags: database, cms-pages

1. We have created a **form using Magento CMS page**. As you know, Form has many fields like Name, Email, etc. In our form, we have an input field called **School**.
2. We have a **list of schools in the database**.

Now, we want to load the school database records into the Form(CMS page). How can I do that?

Could anyone please help me throughout this?

Thanks in advance. Hope I will get a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

**Below two way available for get data** 
1) I Assume you have created Model and Collection file associated with that tables.

2) In a Block PHP file constructor add one argument (Dependency Injection) like below and store it in a class member variable.

```
 public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Namespace\Modulename\Model\ModelNameFactory $modelNameFactory,

    array $data = array()
) {
    $this->_modelFactory = $modelFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
```

3) Prepare a public method in your block to access collection like below.

```
public function getCollection(){

    return $this->_modelFactory->create()->getCollection();

}
```

4) Loop through each of the collection result.

or You can directly get custom table using **objectmanager** concept,

```
$objectManager =   \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $connection = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection')->getConnection('\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION'); 
    $result1 = $connection->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM tablename");

echo "<pre>";print_r($result1);
```

**Note: Don't use Object Manager instance directly check this for more details: [Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly)**

**Hope, this will help you.**

Comment: Many thanks for your information. Certainly, I will check as per the steps you mentioned. For your info: I didn't create the Model and Collection file yet. Can you please point me out how can I do it?

Comment: @Magentovsmarttec ref link : http://bilalusean.com/create-read-update-delete-crud-magento-2/