# Magento 2 How can i get all out of stock product collection?

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3

I want the collection of products which are **out of stock**.

In my Magento instance, I used a multisource inventory with multiple stocks and sources.

How can I get this functionality with a custom module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
namespace YourCompanyName\YourModuleName\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class YourCustomBlock  extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    protected $_productVisibility;

   public function __construct(Template\Context $context,         
                               \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
                               \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility,
                               array $data = [])
   {
       $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
       $this->_productVisibility = $productVisibility;
       parent::__construct($context, $data);
   }


    public function getProductCollection() {

        $product = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $product->setVisibility($this->productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());
        $product->addWebsiteFilter();
        $product->addStoreFilter();
        $product->addAttributeToSelect('*')->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', true);
        $product = $product
            ->joinField('qty',
                'cataloginventory_stock_item',
                'qty',
                'product_id=entity_id',
                '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                'left'
            )
            ->addAttributeToSelect('stock_status')
            ->addAttributeToSort ( 'entity_id', 'DESC' )
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
            ->load();
        return $product;
    }

}
```

or **using object manager**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $productCollection->create();
$collection->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', true);
$collection = $collection
->joinField('qty',
        'cataloginventory_stock_item',
        'qty',
        'product_id=entity_id',
        '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
        'left'
    )
    ->addAttributeToSelect('stock_status')
    ->load();
```

**You should not use the ObjectManager directly [check here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/117103/68695)!**

Answer (score 0):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager- 
>create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$productCollection = $productCollectionFactory
->create()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
->joinField('stock_item', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'qty', 
'product_id=entity_id', 'qty=0')
->setPageSize(8)
->load();
```

Comment: Thanks for your support but it will give products which have default stock inventory, but in my case, there is multisource inventory. and it is not working for multisource inventory. I have updated the question.