# magento 2 how to display simple product image instead of configurable product image in order detail?

Tags: magento2.2, sales-order, product-images

I can successfully display the configurable product image in order detail page with the following code.

```
/** @var  $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Item\Renderer\DefaultRenderer */
$_item = $block->getItem();
$imageBuilder = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder');
```

```
<span style="display: table-cell;"><?= $imageBuilder->setProduct($_item->getProduct())->setImageId('cart_page_product_thumbnail')->create()->toHtml(); ?></span>
```

But I want the image is the simple product one. Like if I buy the blue one, it shows the blue image I set in admin.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to load the simple product from sku field of sales_order_item and then you get  simple product image.

```
<?php

/** @var  $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Item\Renderer\DefaultRenderer */
$_item = $block->getItem();
$imageBuilder = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder');

if($_item->getProductType() == 'configurable'){
    $productObject = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
    $simpleproduct = $productObject->loadByAttribute('sku', $_item->getSku());
?>
    <span style="display: table-cell;"><?= $imageBuilder->setProduct($simpleproduct)->setImageId('cart_page_product_thumbnail')->create()->toHtml(); ?></span>
<?php
}else{

?>
<span style="display: table-cell;"><?= $imageBuilder->setProduct($_item->getProduct())->setImageId('cart_page_product_thumbnail')->create()->toHtml(); ?></span>
<?php } ?>
```

### Note that: USED OF direct object Manager is not a good idea

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It really helps but I'm thinking that we don't need to separate if it's simple product. We can use 'sku' to get the image for both simple and configurable product type.

Comment: why directly using object manager is not a good idea?

Comment: See the article,  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly