# Magento2 Admin Grid Image Display

Tags: magento2, grid

> ***Note: I am not using UI component***

I have a file `Grid.php` where I have a column `image`, in this column, image URL is populating

I want to show the image in this column instead of image URL

Comment: want to show thumbnail in grid???

Comment: Yes, could be thumbnail. I have custom grid for a custom table where image url is appearing, I want image against URL in grid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured out the solution of this:

In my `Grid.php` I have used 'frame_callback' function like this:

```
$this->addColumn(
    'image',
    [
        'header' => __('Image'),
        'index' => 'image',
        'type' => 'image',
        'frame_callback' => array($this, 'show_image'),
    ]
);
```

After this, I have added `show_image` function at the end of the file:

```
public function show_image($value)
{
    if (empty($value)){
        return '';
    }
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $mediaUrl = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
    $width = 150;
    return "<img src='" . $mediaUrl . $value . "' width='" . $width . "'/>";
}
```

After this, image is now appearing on my custom grid.

Comment: you can use my code that is correct method and  Do not use directly object manager
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly

Answer (score 2):

In your `Grid.php` define like below

```
$this->addColumn(
    'image',
    array(
        'header' => __('Image'),
        'index' => 'image',
        'renderer'  => '\Vendorname\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Modulename\Grid\Renderer\Image',
    )
);
```

Create `Image.php` under

> \Vendorname\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Modulename\Grid\Renderer\

and paste below code

```
namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Modulename\Grid\Renderer;

class Image extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer
{
    protected $_storeManager;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,      
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;        
    }


    public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
    {
        $img;
        $mediaDirectory = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
           \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
       );
        if($this->_getValue($row)!=''):
            $imageUrl = $mediaDirectory.$this->_getValue($row);
            $img='<img src="'.$imageUrl.'" width="100" height="100"/>';
        else:
            $img='<img src="'.$mediaDirectory.'Modulename/no-img.jpg'.'" width="100" height="100"/>';
        endif;
        return $img;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have used `frame_callback` function and it is working fine for me. But it could also be done through renderer that you have mentioned. Thanks for the effort. +1