# Magento2 Admin form for Image Upload

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, adminform

> I have created a module in magento2 to upload image field. Saving the
>   image hiding the image upload field option in backend

```
public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        if($data) {
            if(isset($data['is_active']) && $data['is_active'] === 'true') {
                $data['is_active'] = Notification::STATUS_ENABLED;
            }
            if(empty($data['notification_id'])){
                $data['notification_id'] = null;

            }

            if(isset($data['image']) && is_array($data['image'])){
                $data['image']=$data['image'][0]['name'];
            } 
            else{
                $data['image'] = null;
            }
            /** @var  \Dzinehub\PushNotification\Model\Notification $notification */
            $model = $this->notificationFactory->create();

            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('notification_id');

            if($id) {
                try{
                    $model = $this->notificationRepository->getById($id);
                } catch(LocalizedException $e) {
                    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Notification no longer exists'));
                    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
                }
            }
             $model->setData($data);

            /* var_dump($data);
             die;*/

              try {
                $this->notificationRepository->save($model);
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You saved the notification.'));
                $this->dataPersistor->clear('dzpushnotif');
                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['notification_id' => $model->getId()]);
                }
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the notification.'));
            }

            $this->dataPersistor->set('dzpushnotif', $data);
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['notification_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('notification_id')]);
        }
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        }
```

> Also, how to move the image from temporary directory using this
>   function moveFileFromTmp. Any help on this issue?

Comment: can you check this [link  for image upload in admin form](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269632/how-to-do-image-uploader-in-the-custom-form-field-in-magento-2-backend)

Answer (score 1):

For Image upload in admin follow the below link

can you check this [link for image upload in admin form](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269632/how-to-do-image-uploader-in-the-custom-form-field-in-magento-2-backend) And also refer this [link for save image](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269883/in-admin-form-after-edit-and-save-a-form-in-db-already-stored-image-save-as-bla)

Comment: Image is saving in the backend. But after saving upload option is hiding in the admin form and also how to move the image from tmp location to base location

Comment: can you check this [link to solve that issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269883/in-admin-form-after-edit-and-save-a-form-in-db-already-stored-image-save-as-bla)

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269883/in-admin-form-after-edit-and-save-a-form-in-db-already-stored-image-save-as-bla