# Magento 2: How to add custom attributes to Customer group?

Tags: magento2, attributes, customer, customer-group

I want to add a custom attribute(image upload) here on customer groups.
I have searched a lot. can anyone help me about that?
[image]

Comment: I think you need to create a patch attribute for this

Comment: https://belvg.com/blog/how-to-add-new-column-on-admin-customer-group-page-in-magento-2-x.html#:~:text=You%20can%20add%20a%20custom,%2Dto%2Ddatabase%2F).&text=1-,ALTER%20TABLE%20%60customer_group%60%20ADD%20%60admin_comment%60%20VARCHAR(255,a%20typical%20structure%20(with%20registration.

Answer (score 0):

Using db_schema.xml, you need to [add a column](https://www.thecoachsmb.com/how-to-add-an-extra-column-in-your-existing-magento-2-table/) to the appropriate table check this file to get information about it : `vendor/magento/module-customer/etc/db_schema.xml`.

Form is made the old way. You will need to have a preference for `vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/Adminhtml/Group/Edit/Form.php` to extend it and add the appropriate field. That should do the trick but I didn't use it for long time : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/269641/9489.