# In admin form after edit and save a form in db, already stored image save as blank in db in magento 2

Tags: magento2, image-upload

when a edit admin form, Previously saved image path become blank in db how to solve this problem in magento 2
I m done a image upload and save into db by using [this code](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269632/how-to-do-image-uploader-in-the-custom-form-field-in-magento-2-backend/269641?noredirect=1#comment383069_269641)

1. In form upload and save a image in database

[image]

2. after edit and save a form again, image will be blank
   [image]

Please someone help me solve this issue

**Updated**
Controller file: Save.php

```
<?php

namespace Cm\Productlabel\Controller\Adminhtml\Label;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Save extends Action
{

    public function __construct(
      Action\Context $context

     )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);


    }

    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Cm_Productlabel::save');
    }

   public function execute()
   {
      $isPost = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
      $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
      if ($isPost) {
            $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Cm\Productlabel\Model\Productlabel');
         $postId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('productlabel_id');

         if ($postId) {
            $model->load($postId);
         }
         $formData = $this->getRequest()->getParam('label');
        if(!empty($post['proimage']['value']))
       {
            $imageName = $post['proimage']['value'];
            $post['proimage'] = $imageName;
        }
         $model->setData($formData);

    $imagePost = $this->getRequest()->getFiles('proimage');
    $fileName = ($imagePost && array_key_exists('name', $imagePost)) ? $imagePost['name'] : null;
   if($imagePost && $fileName) {
    try {
        $uploader = $this->_objectManager->create(
            'Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader',
            ['fileId' => 'proimage']
        );
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
        $imageAdapterFactory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory')
            ->create();
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
        $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
        $mediaDirectory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem')
            ->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);

        $result = $uploader->save(
            $mediaDirectory
                ->getAbsolutePath('Cm/Productlabel')
        );
        $model->setProimage('Cm/Productlabel'.$result['file']);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        if ($e->getCode() == 0) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}





         try {

         // var_dump($model->setProimage( $prev_img ));exit;  // before saving


            $model->save();

            // Display success message
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('The label has been saved.'));

            // Check if 'Save and Continue'
            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
               $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', ['id' => $model->getId(), '_current' => true]);
               return;
            }

            // Go to grid page
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
         } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
         }

         $this->_getSession()->setFormData($formData);
         $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', ['id' => $postId]);
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: check my answer 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/269523/68695

Comment: after edit a form image  save as blank in db   that only its 
not display in  grid, there is no problem in grid, kindly please refer a screenshot https://prnt.sc/nbbz7x

Comment: first check in controller here image url coming or not

Comment: In controller  getparams() value https://prnt.sc/nbe06x

Comment: Please check you save controller. If you are validating the image before saving the data..

Comment: Controller code before save https://prnt.sc/nc0yy1, Image path https://prnt.sc/nc0zas , after command  the var_dump() function and run a controller, db value after save https://prnt.sc/nc1051

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add these two line before  **$model->setData($formData);**

```
if(!empty($post['proimage']['value']))
{
    $imageName = $post['proimage']['value'];
    $post['proimage'] = $imageName;
}
```

Comment: @divyasekar my pleasure

Comment: https://prnt.sc/nc1uwy

Comment: ok no problem @divyasekar

Comment: ok i will accept it after reach a time limit @rakesh

Answer (score 2):

Please check your save controller. If you are validating the image before saving the data.

```
if (isset($data['proimage'][0]['name']) && isset($data['proimage'][0]['tmp_name'])) {
            $data['proimage'] ='/banners/'.$data['proimage'][0]['name'];
        } elseif (isset($data['proimage'][0]['name']) && !isset($data['image'][0]['tmp_name'])) {
            $data['proimage'] =$data['proimage'][0]['name'];
        } else {
            $data['proimage'] = null;
        }
 $model->setData($data);
```

Comment: I will try and update u @mandar

Comment: It was not working its not edit a data it will add a new row

Comment: @divyasekar can you add you Save controller code?